# Fortnightly Topic Challenge #1: Movies

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

*Link to [other](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3Aquestion%20Fortnightly%20Topic%20Challenge%20%23) Fortnightly Topics.*

---

This will be the first installment of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge described [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2841/should-we-have-weekly-fortnightly-topic-challenges) with topics suggested and voted for [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/what-should-be-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges). This fortnight's topic is [movies](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movies) and will span from Sep. 9-22

Since the author of that post is currently unable to proceed with operations but the community interest remains (to my knowledge at least), I will take over making this post and editing in the current topic (hopefully no one sees this as an affront or imposition, and if someone else wants to handle this, feel free).  Again, this fortnight's topic will be [movies](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movies). At the end of the fortnight I (or someone else) will compile the list of questions featuring this topic and post it as an answer to this question.

In the meantime, please go [propose and vote on future challenges!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/what-should-be-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges)

Everyone have fun and happy puzzling!!

Comment: out of curiosity, is there a winner? Or is it just to challenge one another to come up with neat themed puzzles? (which is totally fine!!!!)

Comment: I felt that went rather well.

Comment: @Spacemonkey to my knowledge, there is no single winner. I don't know that there'd be any benefit to going that route either. If you have a suggestion though, nothing is set in stone

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**List of all puzzles in this event:**

1. [How do you rank these actors](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/22043/how-do-you-rank-these-actors) by [CodeNewbie](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/12700/codenewbie)
2. [Well-known quotations](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/22050/well-known-quotations) by [Gordon K](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/14135/gordon-k)
3. [What is a Spiel/Spieg Word™?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/22051/what-is-a-spiel-spieg-word) by [NeedAName](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/13970/needaname)
4. [Expert puzzler, apprentice movie-maker](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/22057/expert-puzzler-apprentice-movie-maker) by [Bailey M](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/11475/bailey-m)
5. [Gold Lamé swimsuit, / Asthmatic dad's dead. / Sorry Luke, she's your sister](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/22071/gold-lam%c3%a9-swimsuit-asthmatic-dads-dead-sorry-luke-shes-your-sister) by [A E](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/4050/a-e)
6. [What really happened - Who am I?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/22075/what-really-happened-who-am-i) by [Aggie Kidd](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/9951/aggie-kidd)
7. [Scripts are like a box of sweets](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/22084/scripts-are-like-a-box-of-sweets) by [Eli](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/12332/eli)
8. [Encrypted Titles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/22094/encrypted-titles) by [NeedAName](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/13970/needaname)
9. [This isn't really my life story](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/22110/this-isnt-really-my-life-story) by [Gordon K](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/14135/gordon-k)
10. [Reverend Spooner's Favorite Movies](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/22114/reverend-spooners-favorite-movies) by [dennisdeems](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/4385/dennisdeems)
11. [Maybe we're all just pavement oil](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/22109/maybe-were-all-just-pavement-oil) by [spacemonkey](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/11251/spacemonkey)
12. [Find The Third One From The First Two Riddles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/22199/find-the-third-one-from-the-first-two-riddles) by [AeJey](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/2730/aejey)
13. [Shakespeare. William Shakespeare](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/22206/shakespeare-william-shakespeare) by [NeedAName](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/13970/needaname)
14. [Art Thou Addressing Me?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/22243/art-thou-addressing-me) by [NeedAName](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/13970/needaname)
15. [A complete Change](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/22249/a-complete-change-who-am-i) by [Aggie Kidd](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/9951/aggie-kidd)
16. [Haiku about Movies](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/22318/haiku-about-movies-we-are-engaged-year-after-year-year-after-year) by [Eli](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/12332/eli)
17. [What's In A Name](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/22360/whats-in-a-name) by [NeedAName](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/13970/needaname)
18. [Actual Movie Haikus](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/22363/actual-movie-haikus-im-sorry-father-i-should-not-have-run-away-i-will-ave) by [derium](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/14418/derium)
19. [I've seen these movies countless ties](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/22382/ive-seen-these-movies-countless-ties) by [Gordon K](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/14135/gordon-k)
20. [Morse of the films that I've watched a lot](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/22396/morse-of-the-films-that-ive-watched-a-lot) by [Gordon K](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/14135/gordon-k)
21. [Movies in movies](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/22415/movies-in-movies) by [awesomepi](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/167/awesomepi)

<sub>You can also find the list [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=[movies]%20created%3a2015-9-7..2015-9-22%20is%3aquestion).</sub>