# Fortnightly Topic Challenge #35: Restricted Title 1

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This is the first installment of the Fortnightly Topic Challenges Rerun described [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2841) and the thirty-fifth installment of the FTCs overall, with topics suggested and voted on [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6339). This fortnight's topic is "***Restricted Title***" (suggested by [Sp3000](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/445/sp3000)) and will span from the **28th of May to the 10th of June**. During this period, we will compile the list of questions with a relevant title and post it as an answer to this question.

**In the meantime, please go and [propose and vote on future challenges!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6339)**

Everyone have fun, and happy puzzling!

---

<sub>*Link to [other](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20title%3a%22Fortnightly%20Topic%20Challenge%20%23) Fortnightly Topic Challenges.*</sub>

***NOTE***
The Restricted Title topic challenge does not have a specific tag associated; instead titles must be selected from a filtered list. **Due to the nature of this challenge, please add your own questions to the list below.** In this challenge, the possible titles are derived from the first 1000 xkcd comic titles. The [original suggestion](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6339/fortnightly-topic-challenges-rerun/6343#6343) is copied to this post for posterity.

> ## Restricted Title
>
> Usually the title is decided upon later in the puzzle creation process, chosen to be fitting and often to provide a hint/reference. Here we're going to go the other way.
>
> Below is a list of the [titles](https://explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/List_of_all_comics_(full)) for the first 1000 [xkcd comics](http://xkcd.com), filtered down to only those titles which are family-friendly and would be valid for posting as a Stack Exchange question title (≥ 15 characters). 
>   Pick any of the 297 remaining titles and use it as-is (preserving case, part numbers, parenthesised words, etc.) — this will be the title of your new puzzle.
>
> The title should make sense given the puzzle, whether that be through the puzzle's presentation, mechanics or answer. The more fitting, the better!
>
> Don't be discouraged if you see that someone else has posted a puzzle with a title you had intended to use. If anything, it can be interesting to see what different approaches people take for the same title, should there be any collisions!
>
> The list:
>
> ```
> Barrel - Part 1
> Petit Trees (sketch)
> Island (sketch)
> Landscape (sketch)
> Girl sleeping (Sketch -- 11th grade Spanish class)
> Serenity is coming out tomorrow
> Barrel - Part 2
> Just Alerting You
> Monty Python -- Enough
> Barrel - Part 3
> Godel, Escher, Kurt Halsey
> Barrel - Part 4
> Barrel - Part 5
> Counter-Red Spiders
> Why Do You Love Me?
> Valentine - Karnaugh
> Valentine - Heart
> Abusive Astronomy
> Bored with the Internet
> Iambic Pentameter
> Attention, shopper
> National Language
> Digital Rights Management
> Escher Bracelet
> Gravitational Mass
> Profile Creation Flowchart
> Back to the Future
> Moral Relativity
> Parallel Universe
> Wright Brothers
> Snakes on a Plane! 2
> M.C. Hammer Slide
> Firefox and Witchcraft - The Connection?
> Baring My Heart
> Computational Linguists
> Worst Band Name Ever
> Centrifugal Force
> Marketing Interview
> Red Spiders Cometh
> The Fast and the Furious
> Content Protection
> Music Knowledge
> I Have Owned Two Electric Skateboards
> Parody Week: Achewood
> Parody Week: Megatokyo
> Parody Week: TFD and Natalie Dee
> Parody Week: A Softer World
> Parody Week: Dinosaur Comics
> A Way So Familiar
> Penny Arcade Parody
> Angular Momentum
> Playing Devil's Advocate to Win
> Reverse Euphemisms
> Words that End in GRY
> Skateboarding is Not a Crime
> That's What SHE Said
> Automatic Doors
> Not Really Into Pokemon
> e to the pi times i
> Snacktime Rules
> Matrix Transform
> Working for Google
> The Perfect Sound
> Map of the Internet
> Command Line Fu
> Right-Hand Rule
> Candy Button Paper
> What xkcd Means
> Regular Expressions
> Hamster Ball Heist
> Ghostbusters Marathon
> The Problem with Wikipedia
> Romantic Drama Equation
> e to the pi Minus pi
> Nintendo Surgeon
> Valentine's Day
> Chess Enlightenment
> A New CAPTCHA Approach
> Collecting Double-Takes
> Keyboards are Disgusting
> Appropriate Term
> Tabletop Roleplaying
> Labyrinth Puzzle
> Factoring the Time
> Highway Engineer Pranks
> Online Communities
> Conspiracy Theories
> Clichéd Exchanges
> The Glass Necklace
> Regarding Mussolini
> Choices: Part 1
> Choices: Part 2
> Choices: Part 3
> Choices: Part 4
> Choices: Part 5
> Linux User at Best Buy
> Electromagnetic Spectrum
> With Apologies to The Who
> Black Hat Support
> Online Package Tracking
> Wikipedian Protester
> Nighttime Stories
> Orphaned Projects
> Excessive Quotation
> Interesting Life
> With Apologies to Robert Frost
> That Lovin' Feelin'
> Engineering Hubris
> Effect an Effect
> Exploits of a Mom
> Getting Out of Hand
> Post Office Showdown
> Diet Coke+Mentos
> Christmas Back Home
> Responsible Behavior
> Compiler Complaint
> The Data So Far
> Real Programmers
> The Drake Equation
> Advanced Technology
> Travelling Salesman Problem
> Important Life Lesson
> Large Hadron Collider
> 1,000 Miles North
> Convincing Pickup Line
> Electric Skateboard (Double Comic)
> Mistranslations
> Restraining Order
> Zealous Autoconfig
> The Man Who Fell Sideways
> Stove Ownership
> Forks and Spoons
> Making Hash Browns
> Fortune Cookies
> Every Damn Morning
> xkcd Goes to the Airport
> How it Happened
> Internet Argument
> xkcd Loves the Discovery Channel
> Know Your Vines
> Macgyver Gets Lazy
> I Am Not Good with Boomerangs
> In Popular Culture
> Things Fall Apart
> Upcoming Hurricanes
> Freemanic Paracusia
> Voting Machines
> Quantum Teleportation
> The End is Not for a While
> House of Pancakes
> Further Boomerang Difficulties
> The Staple Madness
> Listen to Yourself
> Fiction Rule of Thumb
> I am Not a Ninja
> Steal This Comic
> Morning Routine
> Secretary: Part 1
> Secretary: Part 2
> Secretary: Part 3
> Secretary: Part 4
> Secretary: Part 5
> A Bunch of Rocks
> Theft of the Magi
> Experimentation
> Induced Current
> Egg Drop Failure
> Alternate Currency
> No One Must Know
> Marshmallow Gun
> 2008 Christmas Special
> I Know You're Listening
> Converting to Metric
> Sledding Discussion
> Contingency Plan
> Genetic Algorithms
> It Might Be Cool
> Space Elevators
> Sierpinski Valentine
> Neutrality Schmeutrality
> Not Enough Work
> Alternative Energy Revolution
> No Pun Intended
> Lithium Batteries
> Security Question
> Matrix Revisited
> Parental Trolling
> Tag Combination
> The Race: Part 1
> The Race: Part 2
> The Race: Part 3
> The Race: Part 4
> The Race: Part 5
> Mission to Culture
> Designated Drivers
> Voynich Manuscript
> Android Girlfriend
> Android Boyfriend
> Qwertial Aphasia
> Disaster Voyeurism
> Supported Features
> Newton and Leibniz
> Tech Support Cheat Sheet
> Blockbuster Mining
> Locke and Demosthenes
> Lincoln-Douglas
> So Bad It's Worse
> Movie Narrative Charts
> Two-Party System
> iPhone or Droid
> Academia vs. Business
> Spinal Tap Amps
> Natural Parenting
> Researcher Translation
> Christmas Plans
> Science Montage
> Dimensional Analysis
> Self-Description
> Semicontrolled Demolition
> Children's Fantasy
> Tensile vs. Shear Strength
> You Hang Up First
> Science Valentine
> Honor Societies
> Principle of Explosion
> Devotion to Duty
> Collatz Conjecture
> The Flake Equation
> Computer Problems
> Circuit Diagram
> The Tell-Tale Beat
> Infrastructures
> Geeks and Nerds
> Worst-Case Scenario
> Interdisciplinary
> University Website
> Savannah Ancestry
> I Don't Want Directions
> Conditional Risk
> Stephen Hawking
> Beautiful Dream
> Online Communities 2
> Pumpkin Carving
> The Economic Argument
> Five-Minute Comics: Part 1
> Five-Minute Comics: Part 2
> Five-Minute Comics: Part 3
> Guest Week: Jeph Jacques (Questionable Content)
> Guest Week: David Troupes (Buttercup Festival)
> Guest Week: Bill Amend (FoxTrot)
> Guest Week: Jeffrey Rowland (Overcompensating)
> Guest Week: Zach Weiner (SMBC)
> My Business Idea
> Positive Attitude
> Arsenic-Based Life
> Genetic Analysis
> Stingray Nebula
> Complex Conjugate
> World According to Americans
> Consecutive Vowels
> Learning to Cook
> Trochee Fixation
> Major in the Universe
> Compass and Straightedge
> Server Attention Span
> Time Management
> Craigslist Apartments
> Future Timeline
> Null Hypothesis
> Teaching Physics
> Elevator Inspection
> Chain of Command
> Darmok and Jalad
> Advertising Discovery
> Worst-Case Shopping
> Magic School Bus
> Manual Override
> YouTube Parties
> Delivery Notification
> Strunk and White
> Days of the Week
> Missed Connections
> Password Strength
> Depth Perception
> Hurricane Names
> The Corliss Resolution
> The Important Field
> Alternative Literature
> The General Problem
> Occulting Telescope
> Map Projections
> Wisdom of the Ancients
> Space Launch System
> Percentage Points
> Drinking Fountains
> Advent Calendar
> Making Things Difficult
> ```

Comment: Can we make multiple puzzles for this challenge or are we limited to just one entry?

Comment: @TreFox You can make multiple! (Just make sure you put a fair bit of effort into them.)

Comment: I'm so happy that xkcd was chosen as the theme of the challenge! Also, somebody should notify Randall Munroe of this happening.

Answer (score 17):

**List of all questions published as part of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge #35:**

- [I Am Not Good with Boomerangs](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66332) by [noedne](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/48337)
- [Candy Button Paper](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66355) by [Riley](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/41566)
- [Consecutive Vowels](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66359) by [stacksfiller](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/33827)
- [Stingray Nebula](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66371) by [Alconja](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5208)
- [Regular Expressions](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66381) by [Bass](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/36023)
- [Making Things Difficult](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66407) by [ManyPinkHats](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/48964)
- [Hurricane Names](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66416) by [Dragonrage](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/17028)
- [Not Really Into Pokemon](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66423) by [Kendra](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/38382)
- [Voynich Manuscript](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66427) by [TreFox](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/14414)
- [Barrel - Part 1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66440) by [Riley](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/41566)
- [Chess Enlightenment](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66441) by [stacksfiller](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/33827)
- [Tag Combination](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66447) by [noedne](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/48337)
- [Wisdom of the Ancients](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66485) by [Sensoray](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/38344)
- [That's What SHE Said!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66488) by [QuantumTwinkie](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/34530)
- [Worst Band Name Ever](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66496) by [Kendra](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/38382)
- [What xkcd Means](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66499) by [Deusovi](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/11876)
- [Island (sketch)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66527) by [stacksfiller](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/33827)
- [Barrel - Part 2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66531) by [Riley](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/41566)
- [A Bunch of Rocks](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66568) by [Minh Tran](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/49683)
- [Labyrinth Puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66580) by [stacksfiller](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/33827)
- [Barrel - Part 3](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66590) by [Riley](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/41566)
- [Counter-Red Spiders](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66595) by [H Walters](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/46361)
- [Snakes on a Plane! 2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66642) by [Sleafar](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/15632)
- [Nintendo Surgeon](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66659) by [Crozier](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/45816)
- [No Pun Intended](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66661) by [stacksfiller](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/33827)
- [Computational Linguists](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66665) by [Chowzen](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/22519)
- [Children's Fantasy](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66682) by [QuantumTwinkie](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/34530)
- [Bored with the Internet](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66697) by [QuantumTwinkie](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/34530)
- [Listen to Yourself](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66703) by [stacksfiller](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/33827)
- [Barrel - Part 4](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66725) by [Riley](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/41566)
- [Conspiracy Theories](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66732) by [Joe-You-Know](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/48593)
- [Real Programmers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66743) by [stacksfiller](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/33827)
- [Snakes on a Plane!! 2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66751) by [Alconja](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5208)
- [1,000 Miles North](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66771) by [malioboro](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/46016)
- [Arsenic-Based Life](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66803) by [noedne](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/48337)
- [Arsenic Based Life](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66806) by [stacksfiller](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/33827)
- [A Way So Familiar](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66826) by [QuantumTwinkie](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/34530)
- [Back to the Future](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66834) by [Rand al'Thor](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5373)
- [Steal This Comic](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66839) by [David Starkey](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/2071)
- [Baring my Heart](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66841) by [Sid](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/23009)
- [Barrel - Part 5](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66856) by [Riley](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/41566)
- [Iambic Pentameter](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66857) by [stacksfiller](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/33827)
- [Why Do You Love Me?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66922) by [Minh Tran](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/49683)
- [Circuit Diagram](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66926) by [phenomist](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/37878)
- [Self-Description](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66927) by [stacksfiller](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/33827)
- [National Language](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66953) by [Sid](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/23009)
- [Five-Minute Comics: Part 1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66968) by [stacksfiller](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/33827)
- [Password Strength](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/67004) by [Zimonze](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/49783)
- [With Apologies to Robert Frost](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/67010) by [Rand al'Thor](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5373/rand-althor)
- [Secretary: Parts 1-5](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/67013) by [Riley](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/41566)
- [I Don't Want Directions](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/67017) by [stacksfiller](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/33827)
- [Five-Minute Comics: Part 2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/67038) by [stacksfiller](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/33827)
- [The Data So Far](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/67052) by [stacksfiller](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/33827)
- *add entries in the form 
  `https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/<question-ID> by [username](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)`*

---

The **highest-voted** three of these are:

- [Labyrinth Puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66580) by
  [stacksfiller](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/33827), with
  a score of **50** at the end of the fortnight.
- [Regular Expressions](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66381) by [Bass](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/36023), with a score
  of **47** at the end of the fortnight.
- [Steal This Comic](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66839) by [David Starkey](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/2071), with a score
  of **35** at the end of the fortnight.

The **most viewed** three of these are:

- [That's What SHE Said!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66488) by [QuantumTwinkie](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/34530), with approximately **7700** views during the fortnight.
- [Real Programmers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66743) by [stacksfiller](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/33827), with approximately **5200** views during the fortnight.
- [Steal This Comic](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66839) by [David Starkey](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/2071), with approximately **3300** views during the fortnight.