# Monthly Topic Challenge #1: Restricted Title: xkcd 1xxx

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This is the first installment of the Monthly Topic Challenges with topics suggested and voted on [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7265). This month's topic is ***"Restricted Title: xkcd 1xxx"*** (suggested by [Lukas Rotter](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/37714)) and will span from the **1st of July to the 31st of July**. During this period, the list of relevant questions will be [automatically compiled](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7368/37714) and posted as an answer to this question.

**In the meantime, please go and [propose and vote on future challenges!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7265)**

Everyone have fun, and happy puzzling!

<sub>*Link to [other](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20title%3a%22Monthly%20Topic%20Challenge%20%23) Monthly Topic Challenges.*</sub>

***NOTE***
The suggestion is copied to this post for posterity.

> ### Restricted Title: xkcd 1xxx
>
> <sub>See [this FTC](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6352/fortnightly-topic-challenge-35-restricted-title-1), which dealt with the first 1000 xkcd comics</sub>
>
> Usually the title is decided upon later in the puzzle creation process, chosen to be fitting and often to provide a hint/reference. Here we're going to go the other way.
>
> Below is a list of the [titles](https://explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/List_of_all_comics_(full)) for [xkcd comics](http://xkcd.com/) 1000-1999, filtered down to those titles which are a valid Stack Exchange question title (≥ 15 characters). Pick any of the 300 remaining titles and use it as-is (preserving case, part numbers, parenthesised words, etc.) — this will be the title of your new puzzle.
>
> The title should make sense given the puzzle, whether that be through the puzzle's presentation, mechanics or answer. The more fitting, the better!
>
> Don't be discouraged if you see that someone else has posted a puzzle with a title you had intended to use. If anything, it can be interesting to see what different approaches people take for the same title, should there be any collisions!
>
> The list:
>
> ```
> Sloppier Than Fiction
> Wrong Superhero
> Wake Up Sheeple
> Valentine Dilemma
> Backward in Time
> Good Cop, Dadaist Cop
> So It Has Come To This
> Compare and Contrast
> s/keyboard/leopard/
> Lakes and Oceans
> Whites of Their Eyes
> Every Major's Terrible
> Words for Small Sets
> Home Organization
> Argument Victory
> Eyelash Wish Log
> Internal Monologue
> Formal Languages
> Clinically Studied Ingredient
> A Hypochondriac's Nightmare
> Fastest-Growing
> Sports Cheat Sheet
> Cautionary Ghost
> Think Logically
> Killed in Action
> Blurring the Line
> Electoral Precedent
> The Universal Label
> Objects In Mirror
> Epsilon and Zeta
> Frequentists vs. Bayesians
> Arachnoneurology
> Rubber and Glue
> Calendar of Meaningful Dates
> Nothing to Offer
> Kolmogorov Directions
> Drop Those Pounds
> Star Trek into Darkness
> Moving Sidewalks
> Those Not Present
> Virus Venn Diagram
> Rembrandt Photo
> Circumference Formula
> Ineffective Sorts
> Stratigraphic Record
> All Adobe Updates
> Integration by Parts
> Is It Worth the Time?
> Footnote Labyrinths
> Birds and Dinosaurs
> Interstellar Memes
> Combination Vision Test
> Sticks and Stones
> Balloon Internet
> The Pace of Modern Life
> Polar/Cartesian
> Realistic Criteria
> Douglas Engelbart (1925-2013)
> Quantum Mechanics
> Annoying Ringtone Champion
> 10-Day Forecast
> The Mother of All Suspicious Files
> Exoplanet Names
> Preferred Chat System
> Halting Problem
> Alternate Universe
> Privacy Opinions
> Tall Infographics
> Reverse Identity Theft
> Improved Keyboard
> Syllable Planning
> Shoot for the Moon
> Telescope Names
> Exoplanet Neighborhood
> I Don't Own a TV
> File Extensions
> Undocumented Feature
> Buzzfeed Christmas
> Christmas Lights
> Infinite Scrolling
> Goldbach Conjectures
> Questions for God
> Mobile Marketing
> When You Assume
> Types of Editors
> Before the Internet
> Shouldn't Be Hard
> Cosmologist on a Tire Swing
> Heartbleed Explanation
> Airplane Message
> Orbital Mechanics
> Google Announcement
> Astronaut Vandalism
> Manual for Civilization
> People are Stupid
> Clumsy Foreshadowing
> Subduction License
> Research Ethics
> Dominant Players
> Quantum Vacuum Virtual Plasma
> Universal Converter Box
> Worst Hurricane
> March of the Penguins
> Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles
> Suddenly Popular
> My Phone is Dying
> Reduce Your Payments
> Move Fast and Break Things
> The Sake of Argument
> Where Do Birds Go
> Presidential Alert
> AI-Box Experiment
> Background Screens
> Trolley Problem
> Location Sharing
> Troubleshooting
> Apollo Speeches
> Fundamental Forces
> Stories of the Past and Future
> Terry Pratchett
> Upside-Down Map
> Ontological Argument
> Operating Systems
> Scenery Cheat Sheet
> Basketball Earth
> Win by Induction
> Typical Morning Routine
> Sword in the Stone
> Placebo Blocker
> The BDLPSWDKS Effect
> Antique Factory
> Scheduling Conflict
> Strengths and Weaknesses
> Tamagotchi Hive
> Solar System Questions
> Exoplanet Names 2
> Water Phase Diagram
> Every Seven Seconds
> Synonym Movies 2
> Engineer Syllogism
> Car Model Names
> Cyberintelligence
> Trouble for Science
> I Could Care Less
> Picture a Grassy Field
> NASA Press Conference
> Moments of Inspiration
> Keyboard Problems
> Hardware Reductionism
> 30 Days Hath September
> Launch Status Check
> Linguistics Club
> Five-Day Forecast
> Food Combinations
> Baking Soda and Vinegar
> The Three Laws of Robotics
> Watson Medical Algorithm
> Christmas Settings
> 2016 Conversation Guide
> Substitutions 2
> Longer Than Usual
> Possible Undiscovered Planets
> In Case of Emergency
> Super Bowl Context
> Gravitational Waves
> United States Map
> Universal Install Script
> Estimating Time
> Captain Speaking
> City Talk Pages
> Laws of Physics
> Arcane Bullshit
> Timeline of Bicycle Design
> Message in a Bottle
> Full-Width Justification
> Recent Searches
> Substitutions 3
> My Friend Catherine
> Time-Tracking Software
> Phishing License
> Intervocalic Fortition
> Theft Quadrants
> Speed and Danger
> Home Itch Remedies
> Genetic Testing
> Walking Into Things
> Time Travel Thesis
> Meteorite Identification
> Linear Regression
> Number of Computers
> Migrating Geese
> Earth Temperature Timeline
> Fashion Police and Grammar Police
> Manhattan Project
> Datacenter Scale
> Fixing Problems
> Spider Paleontology
> Future Archaeology
> Interplanetary Experience
> Tornado Safety Tips
> Never Seen Star Wars
> Startup Opportunity
> Adjective Foods
> Things You Learn
> Interest Timescales
> Appliance Repair
> Bad Map Projection: Liquid Resize
> Telescopes: Refractor vs Reflector
> Bird/Plane/Superman
> Soda Sugar Comparisons
> All You Can Eat
> Bad Map Projection: Time Zones
> Decision Paralysis
> Location Reviews
> Unpublished Discoveries
> Borrow Your Laptop
> Best-Tasting Colors
> Mispronunciation
> Rayleigh Scattering
> Security Advice
> Existential Bug Reports
> Hottest Editors
> Identification Chart
> Survivorship Bias
> ISS Solar Transit
> ISS Solar Transit 2
> Photo Library Management
> Random Obsessions
> Machine Learning
> Genetic Testing Results
> Anti-Drone Eagles
> Glacial Erratic
> Air Force Museum
> Magnetohydrodynamics
> Existence Proof
> Sports Knowledge
> Particle Properties
> Wifi vs Cellular
> Russell's Teapot
> Physics Confession
> Eclipse Flights
> Positive and Negative Reviews
> Emoji Movie Reviews
> Backup Batteries
> Geologic Faults
> Computers vs Humans
> Eclipse Searches
> Eclipse Science
> Earth Orbital Diagram
> Supervillain Plan
> Ringer Volume/Media Volume
> Typing Notifications
> Two Down, One to Go
> Obsolete Technology
> Worrying Scientist Interviews
> Active Ingredients Only
> Making Progress
> Credit Card Rewards
> Digital Resource Lifespan
> Defensive Profile
> Twitter Verification
> Nightmare Email Feature
> Temperature Preferences
> How to Make Friends
> Interstellar Asteroid
> The Moon and the Great Wall
> Self-Driving Car Milestones
> Argument Timing
> Virtual Assistant
> The True Meaning of Christmas
> IATA Airport Abbreviations
> Meltdown and Spectre
> 2016 Election Map
> The Food Size Cycle
> Memorable Quotes
> Universal Dreams
> The End of the Rainbow
> Scientific Paper Graph Quality
> Campaign Fundraising Emails
> Chicken Pox and Name Statistics
> Super Bowl Watch Party
> Backpack Decisions
> The History of Unicode
> Impostor Syndrome
> Self-Driving Issues
> Namespace Land Rush
> Spatial Orientation
> Background Apps
> Smart Home Security
> Conversational Dynamics
> Friendly Questions
> Congressional Testimony
> Turkish Delight
> Rickrolling Anniversary
> Misinterpretation
> Python Environment
> Research Areas by Size and Countedness
> Fatal Crash Rate
> Business Update
> Selection Effect
> ```

Comment: I don't know how I feel about a list that doesn't include https://xkcd.com/1337/

Comment: Somewhat sad about not being able to use one of the name of one of xkcd's best comics (if not the best), talking about [Time](https://xkcd.com/1190) of course.

Comment: Just an idea, but what if a tag was created for these titles like [tag:Monthly-Topic-Challenge] or something else. This way it will be easier to see what titles were used and what is available instead of looking at [the answer below](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7353/78801)?

Comment: @VarunW. I think I recall a discussion about that when we had Fortnightly challenges. In essence, tags on main should be useful descriptors of the puzzle itself. An [MTC] tag would fall under meta information, and perhaps be rather annoying.

Comment: @VarunW. Nice idea but - like Lukas said - such 'meta tags' are [discouraged on the Stack Exchange network](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/). I think the list in the answer to this question does the job well anyway - in fact it presents the information far more succinctly (taking up less screen space) than a tag search on the main site ever would :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**List of all questions published as part of the Monthly Topic Challenge #1:**

| Puzzle | Creator |
| --- | --- |
| [Never Seen Star Wars](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/116896/never-seen-star-wars) | [Lukas Rotter](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/37714) |
| [United States Map](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/116918/united-states-map) | [Amoz](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/70710/amoz) |
| [Basketball Earth](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/116930/basketball-earth) | [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644/stiv) |
| [Words for Small Sets](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/116940/words-for-small-sets) | [Auribouros](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/78764/auribouros) |
| [Upside-Down Map](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/116953/upside-down-map) | [Dertereuui Floireiurtrthr](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/79067/dertereuui-floireiurtrthr) |
| [The End of the Rainbow](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/116966/the-end-of-the-rainbow) | [Auribouros](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/78764/auribouros) |
| [Making Progress](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/117046/making-progress) | [Lukas Rotter](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/37714) |
| [IATA Airport Abbreviations](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/117067/iata-airport-abbreviations) | [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644/stiv) |
| [Where Do Birds Go](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/117072/where-do-birds-go) | [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644/stiv) |
| [File Extensions](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/117076) | [cap](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/57156) |
| [Rickrolling Anniversary](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/117086/rickrolling-anniversary) | [kaitlynmm569](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/71020/kaitlynmm569) |
| [The History of Unicode](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/117102/the-history-of-unicode) | [Dertereuui Floireiurtrthr](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/79067/dertereuui-floireiurtrthr) |
| [Twitter Verification](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/117103/twitter-verification) | [Varun W.](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/78801/varun-w) |
| [The Moon and the Great Wall](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/117109/the-moon-and-the-great-wall) | [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644/stiv) |
| [The BDLPSWDKS Effect](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/117124/the-bdlpswdks-effect) | [noedne](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/48337/noedne) |
| [Best-Tasting Colors](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/117145/best-tasting-colors) | [Auribouros](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/78764/auribouros) |
| [Objects in Mirror](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/117153/objects-in-mirror) | [bobble](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/69582/bobble) |
| [Decision Paralysis](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/117158/decision-paralysis) | [noedne](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/48337/noedne) |
| [Formal Languages](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/117209/formal-languages) | [cap](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/57156/cap) |
| [Memorable Quotes](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/117212/memorable-quotes) | [Jafe](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/41973/jafe) |
| [Estimating T¡me](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/117238/estimating-t-me) | [cap](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/57156/cap) |
| [Longer Than Usual](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/117296/longer-than-usual) | [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644/stiv) |
| [30 Days Hath September](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/117320/30-days-hath-september) | [Cloudy7](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60462/cloudy7) |
| [Whites of Their Eyes](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/117350/whites-of-their-eyes) | [SeptaCube](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/71616/septacube) |

---

---

The **highest-voted** three of these are:

- [IATA Airport Abbreviations](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/117067) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644), with a score of **28** at the end of the month.
- [Where Do Birds Go](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/117072) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644), with a score of **27** at the end of the month.
- [United States Map](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/116918) by [Amoz](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/70710), with a score of **24** at the end of the month.

The **most viewed** three of these are:

- [Where Do Birds Go](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/117072) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644), with **2528** views at the end of the month.
- [Rickrolling Anniversary](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/117086) by [kaitlynmm569](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/71020), with **1530** views at the end of the month.
- [Longer Than Usual](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/117296) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644), with **1452** views at the end of the month.