# How does the bot for Monthly Topic Challenges work?

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

What tasks does the [MTC Bot](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/71801) handle and how? What do we as participants of [Monthly Topic Challenges](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7265) have to do or keep in mind?

Answer (score 8):

<sub>This answer describes the current functionalities of the bot as of 2022/07/17</sub>

---

### General

The [MTC_Bot](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/71801/mtc-bot) handles the creation of new MTC posts, updating the list of all questions part of the current MTC, and the posting of statistics related to it.

It is developed and maintained by the user [Lukas Rotter](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/37714). For questions/feature requests/bug reports, please ping `@LukasRotter` in the [Sphinx's Lair Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14524/the-sphinxs-lair).

### Creation

At the start of each month (UTC), the highest voted answer to the [topic suggestion thread](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7265/monthly-topic-challenges-topic-suggestions) is picked by the bot. **It only considers answers which start with a markdown heading** (`## Title ##`)

The bot also keeps a list of all answer IDs to this question which were already picked, so it will not run into problems if an old answer is still on top. In case of a tie, the bot will pick the oldest answer.

It will then create a new question on meta.puzzling for the topic challenge ([example](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7352/monthly-topic-challenge-1-restricted-title-xkcd-1xxx)) and copy the contents of the suggestion into a blockquote for posterity. This works by fetching the raw HTML content of the answer and making some changes to it, e.g. making it single-line.

Currently, **the bot is unable to handle some elements** inside the content of suggestion answers. In case it encounters one of the elements in the list below, the posted question will be misformatted and will have to be manually edited.

- Markdown tables
- Spoiler blocks
- Blockquotes
- MathJax

### Maintenance of the entry list

Each Monthly Topic Challenge thread contains a list of all puzzles which are part of it ([example](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7353/37714)). This list is kept up-to-date by the bot in near-real-time.

The bot registers all [new activities on questions](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=Active) for PSE. If the question **contains a link to the current MTC** meta question(*), the following will be done:

- Check if the bot has already added this question to the list in the past. If not, continue
- Check if the markdown list already contains this question. If not, continue
- Append the new puzzle to the end of the markdown list.

Resulting behavior in some special situations:

- If the link to the MTC is only edited into the question after it has been posted, the bot will still register it correctly.
- If an entry is manually deleted out of the markdown table, the bot will never consider it again.

On average, this process finishes about 2 seconds after the question has been posted because it can take some time until the question body is available via the API and until the edit request is handled by SE. In case it takes longer than, say, 10 seconds, you can assume there was a problem with the bot.

Any manual edits to the answer containing the entry list do not break the bot as long as the edit does not mess with the **format** of the markdown table. You can delete, add or edit entries as long as each table row is in the following format:

`|[PuzzleTitle](PuzzleLink)|[UserName](UserLink)|`

(*) I chose this very liberal matching pattern for two reasons: 1) Any creative modifications/typos/"misplacements" will be allowed, 2) In case a question contains this link without being part of the MTC: Deleting an entry manually is easier than having to add entries the bot doesn't find. I nonetheless plan on improving this in the future.

### Statistics

At the end of each monthly topic challenge, the bot will edit the entry list answer with some statistics:

- Top 3 puzzles with most upvotes
- Top 3 puzzles with most views

I am planning on adding some unnecessary stats for fun, such as a link to a picture containing a bar chart visualizing each puzzle's views/votes in comparison.

Comment: This is very useful for challenge participants to know and should help to clear up a lot of questions around it. Thanks for explaining :)

Comment: Well, seems like MathJax wasn't that big of an issue for my most recent puzzle, hope I didn't break anything hehe

Comment: @Auribouros That list refers to the suggestions, not the puzzles themselves.

Comment: Aaaah, I see, now I'm less afraid to break stuff, thanks for the clarification !