# Monthly Topic Challenge #6: Is it really that [time] again?

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This is the sixth installment of the Monthly Topic Challenges with topics suggested and voted on [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7265). This month's topic is ***"Is it really that [time](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time) again?"*** (suggested by [Auribouros](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/78764)) and will span from the **1st of January to the 31st of January**. During this period, we will compile the list of relevant questions and post it as an answer to this question.

**In the meantime, please go and [propose and vote on future challenges!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7265)**

Everyone have fun, and happy puzzling!

<sub>*Link to [other](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20title%3a%22Monthly%20Topic%20Challenge%20%23) Monthly Topic Challenges.*</sub>

***NOTE***
The suggestion is copied to this post for posterity.

> ### Is it really that [time](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time) again?
>
> After the [first monthly challenge](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7352/monthly-topic-challenge-1-restricted-title-xkcd-1xxx), I expressed my sadness for not seeing Randall Munroe's best work, the 1190th comic, [Time](https://xkcd.com/time). And then I noticed Puzzling had a tag with the same label as that missing comic!
>
> So, I propose a challenge to create puzzles revolving around time, be it near or far, referencing the "unstoppable progress of existence", or even just the comic. A puzzle that comes to mind when I say this could be [this one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/11913/the-sands-of-time), but there are many more examples, and even more possibilities!
>
> Because after all, why do people solve puzzles if not to have a good time?

Comment: The xkcd link is somewhat obscure if you don't know what's going on there. At the risk of spilling the beans, can I suggest adding a link to https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/1190:_Time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**List of all questions published as part of the Monthly Topic Challenge #6:**

| Puzzle | Creator |
| --- | --- |
| [A Ticking Time Bomb](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/119231) | [TakingNotes](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/54081/takingnotes) |
| [Closed Captioning Available](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/119251/closed-captioning-available) | [Auribouros](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/78764/auribouros) |
| [Blind Date and Times](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/119295/blind-date-and-times) | [Spencer Fleming](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/34617/spencer-fleming) |
| [Only time will tell](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/119305/only-time-will-tell) | [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644/stiv) |
| [Time to get a watch](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/119402/time-to-get-a-watch) | [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644/stiv) |
| [Another predictable sequence: 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 17, etc](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/119484/another-predictable-sequence) | [Scratch---Cat](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/54367/scratch-cat) |
| [Horological Horrors](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/119549/horological-horrors) | [gabbo1092](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/52483/gabbo1092) |
| [Time (and a place) for an odd-one-out puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/119565/time-and-a-place-for-an-odd-one-out-puzzle) | [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644/stiv) |

---

The **highest-voted** three of these are:

- [Time to get a watch](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/119402) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644), with a score of **21** at the end of the month.
- [Only time will tell](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/119305) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644), with a score of **18** at the end of the month.
- [Time (and a place) for an odd-one-out puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/119565) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644), with a score of **12** at the end of the month.

The **most viewed** three of these are:

- [Time to get a watch](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/119402) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644), with **2715** views at the end of the month.
- [Only time will tell](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/119305) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644), with **716** views at the end of the month.
- [Closed Captioning Available](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/119251) by [Auribouros](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/78764), with **403** views at the end of the month.