# Monthly Topic Challenge #16: Restricted Title: xkcd 2000-2500

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This is the sixteenth installment of the Monthly Topic Challenges with topics suggested and voted on [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7265). This month's topic is ***"Restricted Title: xkcd 2000-2500"*** (suggested by [Lukas Rotter](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/37714)) and will span from the **1st of November to the 30th of November**. During this period, we will compile the list of relevant questions and post it as an answer to this question.

**In the meantime, please go and [propose and vote on future challenges!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7265)**

Everyone have fun, and happy puzzling!

<sub>*Link to [other](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20title%3a%22Monthly%20Topic%20Challenge%20%23) Monthly Topic Challenges.*</sub>

***NOTE***
The suggestion is copied to this post for posterity.

> ### Restricted Title: xkcd 2000-2500
>
> <sub>See [this FTC](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6352/fortnightly-topic-challenge-35-restricted-title-1) and [this MTC](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7352/monthly-topic-challenge-1-restricted-title-xkcd-1xxx) for previous xkcd challenges</sub>
>
> Usually the title is decided upon later in the puzzle creation process, chosen to be fitting and often to provide a hint/reference. Here we're going to go the other way.
>
> Below is a list of the [titles](https://explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/List_of_all_comics_(2001-2500)) for [xkcd comics](http://xkcd.com/) 2000-2500, filtered down to those titles which are a valid Stack Exchange question title (≥ 15 characters). Pick any of the 282 remaining titles and use it as-is (preserving case, part numbers, parenthesised words, etc.) — this will be the title of your new puzzle.
>
> The title should make sense given the puzzle, whether that be through the puzzle's presentation, mechanics or answer. The more fitting, the better!
>
> Don't be discouraged if you see that someone else has posted a puzzle with a title you had intended to use. If anything, it can be interesting to see what different approaches people take for the same title, should there be any collisions!
>
> The list:
>
> ```
> Global Temperature Over My Lifetime
> Abandonment Function
> Universal Seat Belt
> Commonly Mispronounced Equations
> Pre-Pandemic Ketchup
> Bad Map Projection: The Greenland Special
> Board Game Argument: Legacy
> Danger Mnemonic
> Board Game Party Schedule
> Linked List Interview Problem
> Indoor Socializing
> No, The Other One
> Alien Visitors 2
> First Time Since Early 2020
> Next Slide Please
> Astronomy Status Board
> Wikipedia Caltrops
> In Your Classroom
> Dimensional Chess
> Muller's Ratchet
> Astrophotography
> 90's Kid Space Program
> After the Pandemic
> Types of Scientific Paper
> Virus Consulting
> Fully Vaccinated
> Aviation Firsts
> Post Vaccine Social Scheduling
> Hammer Incident
> Immune Response
> Epistemic Uncertainty
> Solar System Cartogram
> Post-Vaccine Party
> Geothmetic Meandian
> Vaccine Guidance
> Manage Your Preferences
> Post-Pandemic Hat
> Exposure Models
> Mars Landing Video
> Perseverance Microphones
> Normal Conversation
> Vaccine Ordering
> Metacarcinization
> 1/1,000th Scale World
> Trash Compactor Party
> Solar System Compression Artifacts
> 1/100,000th Scale World
> 1/10,000th Scale World
> Steepen the Curve
> Depth and Breadth
> Viral Vector Immunity
> 2020 Election Map
> Vaccine Tracker
> I Just Don't Trust Them
> Wonder Woman 1984
> Covid Precaution Level
> Contiguous 41 States
> Presidential Middle Names
> Life Before the Pandemic
> Viral Quiz Identity Theft
> Set in the Present
> Electoral Precedent 2020
> Ballot Tracker Tracker
> The True Name of the Bear
> Election Impact Score Sheet
> Probability Comparisons
> Election Screen Time
> Amelia's Farm Fresh Cookies
> Messaging Systems
> Parity Conservation
> Volcano Dinosaur
> Common Star Types
> Evidence of Alien Life
> Gravitational Wave Pulsars
> Polls vs the Street
> Constellation Monstrosity
> University COVID Model
> Stellar Evolution
> Hurricane Hunters
> Standard Model Changes
> Rabbit Introduction
> COVID Risk Comfort Zone
> Wish on a Shooting Star
> 26-Second Pulse
> Mathematical Symbol Fight
> Exposure Notification
> Scientist Tech Help
> Cosmologist Genres
> Pods vs Bubbles
> Asterisk Corrections
> Campfire Habitable Zone
> COVID Risk Chart
> Acceptable Risk
> Universal Rating Scale
> Space Basketball
> Oily House Index
> Five Word Jargon
> Endorheic Basin
> ISO Paper Size Golden Spiral
> Low-Background Metal
> Millennium Problems
> Large Number Formats
> Dynamic Entropy
> Hair Growth Rate
> Eventual Consistency
> Wrong Times Table
> Confidence Interval
> Great Attractor
> Mount St. Helens
> Coronavirus Polling
> 2020 Google Trends
> Turtle Sandwich Standard Model
> Everyone's an Epidemiologist
> Coronavirus Genome 2
> Coronavirus Genome
> Use or Discard By
> Sourdough Starter
> Coronavirus Charts
> RIP John Conway
> New Sports System
> Collector's Edition
> Pathogen Resistance
> Recurring Nightmare
> Coronavirus Worries
> Coronavirus Research
> Scientific Briefing
> Business Greetings
> Coronavirus Name
> Truck Proximity
> Ringtone Timeline
> Grandpa Jason and Grandpa Chad
> Picking Bad Stocks
> Phylogenetic Tree
> Further Research is Needed
> Parker Solar Probe
> Worst Thing That Could Happen
> Networking Problems
> Solar System Changes
> Unsubscribe Message
> Bad Map Projection: South America
> Star Wars Voyager 1
> Parenthetical Names
> Alignment Chart Alignment Chart
> Christmas Presents
> Edible Arrangements
> Thumbtacks And String
> Star Wars Spoiler Generator
> Brussels Sprouts Mandela Effect
> Timeline of the Universe
> AI Hiring Algorithm
> Is it Christmas?
> Group Chat Rules
> How To Deliver Christmas Presents
> Hotel Room Party
> the Time Before And After Land
> Machine Learning Captcha
> Transit of Mercury
> Recombination And Reionization
> Voting Referendum
> Software Updates
> Terminator: Dark Fate
> Imagine Going Back in Time
> Earthquake Early Warnings
> Percent Milkfat
> Faculty:Student Ratio
> Chemistry Nobel
> Cell Phone Functions
> Hours Before Departure
> College Athletes
> Types of Approximation
> Earth-Like Exoplanet
> Foucault Pendulum
> Unreachable State
> Cryptic Wifi Networks
> Nice To E-Meet You
> Dockless Roombas
> How to Send a File
> Well-Ordering Principle
> Conference Question
> Serena Versus the Drones
> Old Game Worlds
> Disappearing Sunday Update
> Unpopular Opinions
> When I'm Back at a Keyboard
> Expiration Date High Score
> Gastroenterology
> How Hacking Works
> Flag Interpretation
> First News Memory
> Trained a Neural Net
> Shadow Biosphere
> Coordinate Precision
> Predictive Models
> Reading in the Original
> Motivated Reasoning Olympics
> Literary Opinions
> Ken Burns Theory
> Diploma Legal Notes
> Effects of High Altitude
> Alternate Histories
> Waiting for the But
> Heists And Escapes
> Adjusting a Chair
> Dangerous Fields
> Reinvent the Wheel
> Wanna See the Code?
> Election Commentary
> M87 Black Hole Size Comparison
> Too Much Talking
> EHT Black Hole Picture
> Percentage Styles
> Industry Nicknames
> 1921 Fact Checker
> Google Trends Maps
> Space Mission Hearing
> Meta Collecting
> Size Venn Diagram
> Light Pollution
> Brain Hemispheres
> Video Orientation
> Normal Distribution
> Differentiation and Integration
> .NORM Normal File Format
> Launch Conditions
> Physics Suppression
> Opportunity Rover
> Invisible Formatting
> Carbonated Beverage Language Map
> Sharing Options
> Modern OSI Model
> Midcontinent Rift System
> Internet Archive
> Technical Analysis
> Models of the Atom
> Missal of Silos
> Consensus New Year
> Million, Billion, Trillion
> Feathered Dinosaur Venn Diagram
> Christmas Eve Eve
> Schwarzschild's Cat
> History Department
> Mercator Projection
> Middle Latitudes
> Cohort and Age Effects
> Horror Movies 2
> Update Your Address
> Airplanes and Spaceships
> Evaluating Tech Things
> Indirect Detection
> Trig Identities
> Who Sends the First Text?
> Modified Bayes' Theorem
> Internal Monologues
> Stanislav Petrov Day
> Unfulfilling Toys
> Social Media Announcement
> Sandboxing Cycle
> Boathouses and Houseboats
> Rolle's Theorem
> Begging the Question
> Supreme Court Bracket
> Dark Matter Candidates
> Repair or Replace
> Voting Software
> Complex Numbers
> Lightning Distance
> Sports Champions
> Software Development
> Negative Results
> An Apple for a Dollar
> OEIS Submissions
> New Phone Thread
> Thorough Analysis
> Newton's Trajectories
> Hertzsprung-Russell Diagram
> Irony Definition
> Brookhaven RHIC
> Customer Rewards
> Presidential Succession
> LeBron James and Stephen Curry
> Clickbait-Corrected p-Value
> xkcd Phone 2000
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**List of all questions published as part of the Monthly Topic Challenge #16:**

| Puzzle | Creator |
| --- | --- |
| [Chemistry Nobel](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/123196/chemistry-nobel) | [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644/stiv) |
| [Presidential Middle Names](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/123204/41973) | [Jafe](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/41973/jafe) |
| [Flag Interpretation](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/123246/flag-interpretation) | [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644/stiv) |
| [Social Media Announcement](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/123316/social-media-announcement) | [Amoz](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/70710/amoz) |
| [College Athletes](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/123430/college-athletes) | [juicifer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/77182/juicifer) |

---

The **highest-voted** three of these are:

- [Flag Interpretation](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/123246) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644), with a score of **24** at the end of the month.
- [Social Media Announcement](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/123316) by [Amoz](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/70710), with a score of **17** at the end of the month.
- [Chemistry Nobel](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/123196) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644), with a score of **9** at the end of the month.

The **most viewed** three of these are:

- [Flag Interpretation](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/123246) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644), with **868** views at the end of the month.
- [Social Media Announcement](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/123316) by [Amoz](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/70710), with **695** views at the end of the month.
- [Chemistry Nobel](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/123196) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644), with **684** views at the end of the month.