# Fortnightly Topic Challenge #36: Twisted Classics 1

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This is the second installment of the Fortnightly Topic Challenges Rerun described [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2841) and the thirty-sixth installment of the FTCs overall, with topics suggested and voted on [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6339). This fortnight's topic is "***Twisted Classics***" (suggested by [Alconja](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/5208)) and will span from the **18th of June to the 1st of July**. During this period, we will compile the list of questions with a relevant title and post it as an answer to this question.

**In the meantime, please go and [propose and vote on future challenges!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6339)**

Everyone have fun, and happy puzzling!

---

<sub>*Link to [other](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20title%3a%22Fortnightly%20Topic%20Challenge%20%23) Fortnightly Topic Challenges.*</sub>

***NOTE***
The Twisted Classics topic challenge does not have a single specific tag associated. **Due to the nature of this challenge, please add your own questions to the list below.** The [suggestion](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6342) is copied to this post for posterity.

> ## Twisted Classics
>
> Make a puzzle that is an alternate take on the sorts of classic puzzles you'd find in a newspaper or an old school puzzle book.
>
> ***The Classics***
>
> Any straightforward, printable puzzle of a well known genre. The kind of thing that your grandma would probably recognise, at least in form. For example (list isn't necessary exhaustive, but should give the general idea):
>
> - [crosswords](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crosswords)
> - [cryptic-crosswords](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptic-crosswords)
> - [logic-grid](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logic-grid)
> - [sudoku](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sudoku)
> - [chess](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chess) <sub><sup>(e.g. win in $x$ moves from current position)</sup></sub>
> - [rebus](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rebus)
> - [word-search](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-search)
> - [word-square](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-square)
> - [word-ladder](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-ladder)
> - [matches](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matches)
>
> ***The Twists***
>
> This is pretty much up to the creator and can be as much or as little of a twist as you want, but some possible suggestions are:
>
> - *Genre fusion* - blend with another genre of puzzle
> - *Meta puzzle* - multiple classics whose solutions lead to another puzzle
> - *Variant rules* - e.g. a sudoku where the centre squares of each 3x3 must always be even, or a logic grid which includes a fixed number of lies amongst its clues
> - *Alternate structures* - e.g. a crossword in a hexagonal grid, or a three dimensional matchstick puzzle
> - *Reverse puzzling* - work backwards from a final state and some other restrictions to a starting condition
> - *{your creative ideas here...}*

Comment: Does [tag:connect-wall] count as a classic?

Comment: @Sleafar - I think yes. In terms of the spirit of the challenge, "game show" fits into the same category as newspapers and puzzle books. I.e. readily available/recognisable to a general audience.

Answer (score 11):

**List of all questions published as part of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge #36:**

- [Just a Regular Word Search](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/67299) by [Riley](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/41566)
- [Word Ladders go to the movies](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/67358) by [David Starkey](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/2071)
- [Twisted Connections](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/67364) by [Sid](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/23009)
- [I don't want to let my friends down](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/67391) by [Joe-You-Know](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/48593)
- [Bumblin' Stumblin' Rumblin' Jumblin'!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/67430) by [Chowzen](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/22519)
- [R.H.P.C. crossword puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/67478) by [Thomas Blue](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/47218)
- [A mazegic square](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/67486) by [crcroberts](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/26415)
- [Code Movie Wall](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/67546/15632) by [Sleafar](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/15632)
- [A globetrotting riddle, with a twist](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/67555) by [SKOG](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/48974)
- [Pikurossword, or: Three-in-One](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/67681) by [Level 51](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/49474)
- [The Vowel Sudoku Challenge](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/67687) by [TwoBitOperation](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/29430)
- [Plot Twist (variety cryptic)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/67727) by [Deusovi](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/11876)
- *add entries in the form 
  `https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/<question-ID> by [username](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)`*

---

The **highest voted** puzzle is [Just a Regular Word Search](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/67299) by [Riley](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/41566), with a score of **38** at the end of the fortnight.

The **most viewed** puzzle is [A mazegic square](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/67486) by [crcroberts](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/26415), with approximately **970** views during the fortnight.