# Fortnightly Topic Challenge #37: Rare and Endangered 1

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This is the third installment of the Fortnightly Topic Challenges Rerun described [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2841) and the thirty-seventh installment of the FTCs overall, with topics suggested and voted on [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6339). This fortnight's topic is "***Rare  and Endangered***" (suggested by [Alconja](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/5208)) and will span from the **9th of July to the 22nd of July**. During this period, we will compile the list of questions with a relevant title and post it as an answer to this question.

**In the meantime, please go and [propose and vote on future challenges!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6339)**

Everyone have fun, and happy puzzling!

---

<sub>*Link to [other](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20title%3a%22Fortnightly%20Topic%20Challenge%20%23) Fortnightly Topic Challenges.*</sub>

***NOTE***
The Rare and Endangered topic challenge does not have a single specific tag associated. **Due to the nature of this challenge, please add your own questions to the list below.** The [suggestion](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6341) is copied to this post for posterity.

> ## Rare and Endangered
>
> ---
>
> Make a puzzle using **at least two tags** that are ***not* in the [top 50 tags](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=popular)** on the site.
>
> I.e. you're trying to make a puzzle whose two primary tags *are not* any of the following*: 
>   [riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/riddle), [mathematics](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematics), [logical-deduction](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logical-deduction), [word](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word), [cipher](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cipher),
>   [enigmatic-puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/enigmatic-puzzle), [wordplay](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wordplay), [pattern](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pattern), [rhyme](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rhyme), [lateral-thinking](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lateral-thinking),
>   [visual](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visual), [geometry](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry), [story](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story), [calculation-puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calculation-puzzle), [knowledge](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/knowledge),
>   [rebus](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rebus), [strategy](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/strategy), [number-sequence](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-sequence), [trivia](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trivia), [combinatorics](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combinatorics),
>   [steganography](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/steganography),  [computer-puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer-puzzle), [english](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/english), [no-computers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/no-computers), [probability](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability),
>   [language](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language), [word-property](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-property), [formation-of-numbers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formation-of-numbers), [cryptic-clues](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptic-clues), [optimization](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization),
>   [liars](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/liars), [chess](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chess), [game](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game), [puzzle-creation](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puzzle-creation), [grid-deduction](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid-deduction),
>   [password](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/password), [number-theory](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-theory), [word-problem](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-problem), [rubiks-cube](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rubiks-cube), [geography](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geography),
>   [sudoku](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sudoku), [situation](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/situation), [open-ended](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-ended), [anagram](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anagram), [poetry](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poetry),
>   [mystery](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mystery), [crosswords](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crosswords), [weighing](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weighing), [letters](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/letters), [checkerboard](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/checkerboard)
>
> ---
>
> **Notes**:
>
> 1. The two "rare" tags should represent *the primary tags of the puzzle*, though you can include other tags (including ones from the top 50) as necessary
>
>    - In other words, it would *not* be in the spirit of the challenge to just create a [riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/riddle) and slap a [animal](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animal)+[limerick](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/limerick) theme/structure on it
>    - But it *would* be in the spirit to create a [three-dimensional](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/three-dimensional)+[mazes](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mazes)+[metapuzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metapuzzle), even if that meant you decided to include [visual](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visual)
> 2. The live top 50 may vary over time. For the purposes of this challenge, the exact list was locked at the start of the fortnight and explicitly stated above.

Comment: Are you allowed to submit multiple entries, or just one?

Comment: @user477343 You can submit multiple

Answer (score 7):

**List of all questions published as part of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge #37:**

- [Good luck finding the odd-one-out](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/68020) by [David Starkey](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/2071)
- [$\verb|Eight Circles|$](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/68048/verbeight-circles) by [user477343](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/42452/user477343)
- [I received an email from a trusted source which contains flags and symbols](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/68071/i-received-an-email-from-a-trusted-source-which-contains-flags-and-symbols?noredirect=1#comment204562_68071) by [Joe-You-Know](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/48593)
- [A Howler's Disposition](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/68277) by [Sensoray](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/38344)
- [An Amazing Nonogram](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/68325/an-amazing-nonogram) by [dcfyj](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/22684)
- *add entries in the form 
  `https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/<question-ID> by [username](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)`*

---

The **highest voted** puzzle is [An Amazing Nonogram](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/68325) by [dcfyj](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/22684), with a score of **13** at the end of the fortnight.

The **most viewed** puzzle is [$\verb|Eight Circles|$](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/68048/verbeight-circles) by [user477343](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/42452/user477343), with approximately **520** views during the fortnight.

Comment: This should probably be changed to a Community Wiki

Comment: Oops, you're right. Completely slipped my mind when making the post; that's fixed now.