# Fortnightly Topic Challenge #38: Reusing Information 1

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This is the fourth installment of the Fortnightly Topic Challenges Rerun described [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2841) and the thirty-seventh installment of the FTCs overall, with topics suggested and voted on [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6339). This fortnight's topic is "***Reusing Information***" (suggested by [phenomist](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/37878)) and will span from the **3rd of September to the 16th of September**. During this period, we will compile the list of questions with a relevant title and post it as an answer to this question.

**In the meantime, please go and [propose and vote on future challenges!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6339)**

Everyone have fun, and happy puzzling!

---

<sub>*Link to [other](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20title%3a%22Fortnightly%20Topic%20Challenge%20%23) Fortnightly Topic Challenges.*</sub>

***NOTE***
The Reusing Information topic challenge does not have a single specific tag associated. **Due to the nature of this challenge, please add your own questions to the list below.** The [suggestion](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6362) is copied to this post for posterity.

> ## Reusing Information
>
> Sometimes, I often particularly enjoy puzzles that reuse the same piece of information over and over. Essentially, it shares the elegance of a well constructed &lit, with whole text serving double-duty. Every word not only is used in entirety for the wordplay part, but the whole phrase could serve as a plausible definition too! Some more examples to follow:
>
> - Encoding several different messages in the same piece of text, each one leading to the next by instructions.
> - Neat meta structures sometimes allow for a set of answers to be used multiple times. The Mystery Hunt [has](http://web.mit.edu/puzzle/www/2011/puzzles/civilization/) [some](http://web.mit.edu/puzzle/www/2013/coinheist.com/sneakers/index.html) [examples](http://web.mit.edu/puzzle/www/2018/full/island/scifi.html).
> - Extraction from the same ciphertext twice, using (ideally) two different ciphers - could be overambitious, but this theme is ambitious.
> - Next, [a picture that has three interpretations](https://puzzle.cisra.com.au/2010/4A-Martial-Law.pdf) - although, this is close to puzzle sets, so try to seamlessly integrate the pieces.
> - Chimera / double [grid-deduction](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid-deduction) puzzles ([see this link](https://nbpuzzles.wordpress.com/2014/06/08/double-puzzles/)). Each grid can work in multiple rulesets.
> - Letters arranged in a grid. Extraction can appear in multiple ways - for example, [some letters could be a word search, others from a grille](http://www.mezzacotta.net/puzzle/2016/4A_AllAstir.pdf).
>
> Note that simply reducing information and applying a recursive step isn't necessarily this - that would be using *newly* acquired data. Going back to square one is this theme's spirit! Then start over, with a fresh look, either by sheer inspiration or by explicit instruction. Have you noticed that this suggestion is itself a puzzle that self-illustrates this theme?

Answer (score 9):

**List of all questions published as part of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge #38:**

- [Making transmitting data safe - double reading](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/71715/making-transmitting-data-safe-double-reading) by [JonMark Perry](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/11497/jonmark-perry)
- [A Periodic Puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/71836/a-periodic-puzzle) by [boboquack](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/30903/boboquack)
- [Understanding the Rookie's Notes](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/71985) by [David Starkey](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/2071/david-starkey)
- [My Final Song to Riley](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72014) by [user477343](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/42452)
- [Ready every count until raspy seers inure oaths noble](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72200/) by [Joe-You-Know](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/48593)
- [Self-Referential Humor](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72306/) by [Level 51](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/49474)
- [Unusual Kakuro Puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72329/) by [Bennett Bernardoni](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/51458)
- [Bongard Metapuzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72335/) by [Riley](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/41566)
- *add entries in the form 
  `https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/<question-ID> by [username](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)`*

---

The **highest-voted** of these is *[A Periodic Puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/71836/a-periodic-puzzle)*, with a score of *21* at the end of the fortnight.

The **most viewed** is *[A Periodic Puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/71836/a-periodic-puzzle)*, with approximately *327* views during the fortnight.

Comment: Now it has a score of $26$ (my upvote included) :P