# Fortnightly Topic Challenge #39: Deep Down in the Dungeon 1

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This is the fifth installment of the Fortnightly Topic Challenges Rerun described [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2841) and the thirty-ninth installment of the FTCs overall, with topics suggested and voted on [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6339). This fortnight's topic is "***Deep Down in the Dungeon***" (suggested by [BmyGuest](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/5840/bmyguest)) and will span from the **24th of September to the 7th of October**. During this period, we will compile the list of questions with a relevant title and post it as an answer to this question.

**In the meantime, please go and [propose and vote on future challenges!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6339)**

Everyone have fun, and happy puzzling!

---

<sub>*Link to [other](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20title%3a%22Fortnightly%20Topic%20Challenge%20%23) Fortnightly Topic Challenges.*</sub>

***NOTE***
The Deep Down in the Dungeon topic challenge does not have a single specific tag associated. **Due to the nature of this challenge, please add your own questions to the list below.** The [suggestion](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6361/48964) is copied to this post for posterity.

> ## Deep Down in the Dungeon
>
> For all (us) fans of RPG games (pen&paper, Computer, or LARP), lets come up with neat little puzzles which can be used to spice up these games. You know the type of setting: Group of adventurers (or single hero) crawls down into the deep dungeon of the evil cult to be presented with this stupid puzzle which locks the next door etc.
>
> Puzzles in this challenge should be:
>
> - **stylish** (whatever that means), with an eye on nice visuals (when appropriate)
> - **usable in the context of such games** without requiring ˋexternalˋ help such as Google searches, computer algorithms or image processing etc.
> - **solveable in a reasonable time-span** by a group of gamers ( <1hr )
> - be presented in an "easily reproducible way" for game masters, i.e. images to be printed etc. are all provided in a nice-to-use manner.

Answer (score 11):

**List of all questions published as part of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge #39:**

- [The Map to Radiance](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72976/the-map-to-radiance) by [Kendra](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/38382/kendra)
- [The Thirteen Doors of Aj Noc'la](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/73289/5208) by [Alconja](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5208/alconja)
- [Lau's Labyrinth](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/73306) by [PerpetualJ](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/51105/perpetualj)
- [Find the song to move along](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/73298/32339) by [CodeLikeBeaker](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/43483/codelikebeaker)
- [A Battered Shield](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/73348/a-battered-shield) by [Mariia Mykhailova](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/51753/mariia-mykhailova)
- [The Corridor of Eon Syras](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/73440/the-corridor-of-eon-syras) by [Sensoray](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/38344/sensoray)
- [The Temple of the Niffugcam](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/73469/the-temple-of-the-niffugcam) by [Excited Raichu](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/52399)
- [Disciple of Gzemnid](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/73531/disciple-of-gzemnid) by [David Starkey](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/2071/david-starkey)
- [Six gems, six shelves, and far too many puzzle rhymes](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/73492/six-gems-six-shelves-and-far-too-many-puzzle-rhymes) by [Stidgeon](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/52777/stidgeon)
- [Welcome to the Dungeon Zoo!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/73582/welcome-to-the-dungeon-zoo) by [Mariia Mykhailova](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/51753/mariia-mykhailova)
- *add entries in the form 
  `https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/<question-ID> by [username](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)`*

---

At the end of the fortnight, the highest-voted and most-viewed puzzle is **[The Thirteen Doors of Aj Noc'la](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/73289/5208)** by **[Alconja](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5208/alconja)** with **61 points** and **3329 views**.