# Fortnightly Topic Challenge #40: Retrograde Analysis

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This is the sixth installment of the Fortnightly Topic Challenges Rerun described [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2841) and the fortieth installment of the FTCs overall, with topics suggested and voted on [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6339). This fortnight's topic is "***Retrograde Analysis***" (suggested by [Riley](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/41566)) and will span from the **15th of October to the 28th of October**. During this period, we will compile the list of relevant questions and post it as an answer to this question.

**In the meantime, please go and [propose and vote on future challenges!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6339)**

Everyone have fun, and happy puzzling!

---

<sub>*Link to [other](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20title%3a%22Fortnightly%20Topic%20Challenge%20%23) Fortnightly Topic Challenges.*</sub>

***NOTE***
Examples of previous [retrograde-analysis](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/retrograde-analysis) puzzles may be found by clicking on the tag, and the full tag wiki entry is [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tags/retrograde-analysis/info).

The original suggestion [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6339/fortnightly-topic-challenges-rerun/6354#6354) provides a list of games that may work well with the challenge, but there are many more, and puzzlers are always encouraged to show creativity by finding interesting puzzles outside of expectation.

Answer (score 8):

**List of all questions published as part of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge #40:**

- [A poorly-designed chess problem](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/73903/a-poorly-designed-chess-problem) by [boboquack](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/30903/boboquack)
- [Retrograde Go Problem (Some Assembly Required)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/73911) by [Bass](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/36023)
- [Murder in the Royal Court](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/73917/murder-in-the-royal-court) by [Excited Raichu](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/52399)
- [How did four chessmen disappear?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/74014/how-did-four-chessmen-disappear) by [Evargalo](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/40223/evargalo)
- [Mate in 0 moves](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/74086/mate-in-0-moves) by [JGibbers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/16466)
- [Fabi and Mag played chess again](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/74080/fabi-and-mag-played-chess-again) by [Evargalo](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/40223/evargalo)
- [Megan mated by a king move](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/74183) by [Rosie F](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/22922)
- [Three free moves, three more moves, mate](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/74193/11110) by [Glorfindel](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/11110/glorfindel)
- [Reconstructing A Chess Game #4](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/74220) by [Evargalo](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/40223/evargalo)
- [Reconstruct a game of Loser Chess](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/74233) by [Evargalo](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/40223/evargalo)
- [A colorful glass circle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/74250/) by [David Starkey](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/2071/david-starkey)
- [Unfinished Snakes and Ladders](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/74275) by [athin](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/28719)
- [Paper, pencil and a bunch of bars](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/74288) by [jafe](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/41973)
- *add entries in the form 
  `https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/<question-ID> by [username](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)`*

---

The **highest-voted** *and* the **most viewed** of these is [Mate in 0 moves](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/74086/mate-in-0-moves) by [JGibbers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/16466), with a score of 82 and approximately 12600 views at the end of the fortnight.

Comment: What does the "colorful glass circle" puzzle has to do with chess?

Comment: @vsz This fortnight's topic is not "Chess" but "Retrograde Analysis". But the question remain: What does the "colorful glass circle" puzzle has to do with Retrograde Analysis ?