# Fortnightly Topic Challenge #41: Short and Sweet

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This is the seventh installment of the Fortnightly Topic Challenges Rerun described [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2841) and the forty-first installment of the FTCs overall, with topics suggested and voted on [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6339). This fortnight's topic is "***Short and Sweet***" (suggested by [Bass](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/36023)) and will span from the **12th of November to the 25th of November**. During this period, we will compile the list of relevant questions and post it as an answer to this question.

**In the meantime, please go and [propose and vote on future challenges!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6339)**

Everyone have fun, and happy puzzling!

<sub>*Link to [other](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20title%3a%22Fortnightly%20Topic%20Challenge%20%23) Fortnightly Topic Challenges.*</sub>

***NOTE***
The Short and Sweet topic challenge does not have a single specific tag associated. **Due to the nature of this challenge, please add your own questions to the list below.** The [suggestion](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6359/48964) is copied to this post for posterity.

> Distill the essence of puzzling into its purest form: a satisfying puzzle that will take no more than five minutes to solve.
>
> You are free to choose any tag combination you like, but you should make the puzzle short, sweet and succinct, so that it can be enjoyed alongside a cup of morning coffee, and it won't make you miss the bus to work.
>
> The main challenge is, of course, keeping the solution interesting and rewarding, while minimising all unnecessary complexity, ornamentation, and sidetracks.
>
> The usual problems, like keeping the answer unique, and not making the puzzle too easy, will also become more pronounced when there's less material to work with. Yet, I'm confident that the Puzzling SE crew can overcome all these obstacles, and make some excellent, high-octane, 5-minute puzzles.
>
> So let's try and get an "Oh, wow!" (or at least an "a-ha!") out of the solver in no more time than it takes to [learn Othello five times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0TzH.jpg)!

Answer (score 11):

**List of all questions published as part of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge #41:**

- [Unusual letter combinations](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/75131) by [GentlePurpleRain](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/4421)
- [Riley 008 by KrOmega](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/75168) by [Krypton Omega](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/51131)
- [Where do I want to go next? 001 by KrOmega (new try)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/75166/where-do-i-want-to-go-next-001-by-kromega-new-try) by [Krypton Omega](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/51131/omega-krypton)
- [Short and Sweet Entry into topical challenge #41](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/75193/short-and-sweet-entry-into-topical-challenge-41) by [DEEM](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/34419/deem)
- [Inner and outer space](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/75223) by [Tom](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/19547)
- [Imma Reflectin Mah Lazer!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/75234/imma-reflectin-mah-lazer) by [Excited Raichu](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/52399/excited-raichu)
- [The Two-Trench Truce](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/75268/) by [Level 51](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/49474)
- [Top ten best ways of transportation](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/75284) by [Thomas Blue](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/47218)
- [Grandpa and his silly questions. Another Grandpa mystery](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/75306/grandpa-and-his-silly-questions-another-grandpa-mystery) by [DEEM](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/34419/deem)
- [The Chessboard Exhibition](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/75442/the-chessboard-exhibition) by [Excited Raichu](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/52399/excited-raichu)
- [There are how many?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/75459/there-are-how-many) by [gabbo1092](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/52483/gabbo1092)
- [Guess what letter conforming each word](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/75500/guess-what-letter-conforming-each-word) by [Mukyuu](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/54032/mukyuu)
- [One at a Time Riddle 001 by KrOmega (new try)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/75540/one-at-a-time-riddle-001-by-kromega-new-try) by [Krypton Omega](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/51131/omega-krypton)
- [Guess Me riddle #2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/75335/guess-me-riddle-2) by [Quark-epoch](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/51989/quark-epoch)
- [A simple connect-wall puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/75688) by [Riley](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/41566)
- [Riley 009 by KrOmega](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/75705/riley-009-by-kromega) by [Krypton Omega](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/51131/omega-krypton)
- [Who am I? I rhymes with flow](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/75698/who-am-i-i-rhymes-with-flow) by [QLAN](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/53985/qlan)
- *add entries in the form 
  `https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/<question-ID> by [username](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)`*

---

The **highest-voted** puzzle is [The Two-Trench Truce](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/75268/) by [Level 51](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/49474) with a score of **54** at the end of the fortnight.
The **most viewed** puzzle is [Unusual letter combinations](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/75131) by [GentlePurpleRain](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/4421) with approximately **2200** views at the end of the fortnight.