# What happened to Fortnightly Topic Challenges?

Tags: discussion, support, topic-challenge

We haven't had a Fortnightly Topic Challenge since the Short and Sweet one, and I enjoy reading those puzzles. What happened?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fortnightly Topic Challenges are a bit of an on-again off-again thing for this site. We don't always get them organised - it seems to be an *"if someone is active and bothered enough to announce it"* kind of thing.

Even back in 2015 there were big gaps: [What should the subjects of our fortnightly topic challenges be? (with updates!)](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3292/5373) Eventually there was a hiatus so long that a *new* meta thread was started to reboot them: [Fortnightly Topic Challenges Rerun!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6339/5373) That didn't last very long, and now it seems there's been another long hiatus.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense.