# Should we continue the Fortnightly Topic Challenges?

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

I noticed, on meta, that the Fortnightly Topic Challenges have stopped on number 41: Short and Sweet. That one is part of the rerun. I would like you to vote in this question if you want to continue. I already have a theme in mind, which is [visual](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visual), and you can give your themes as answers. Please upvote if you still want the series to keep going, and downvote if you don't.

I am just wondering what my fellow users' opinions are on if we should continue the Fortnightly Topic Challenges.

Comment: I'm offering to run the automation again (automatically post the question with the topic & answer with the puzzles + statistics)

Comment: I'm sure there will be plenty of support for this - there have been [several comments to this effect](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=fortnightly&user=&room=14524) in chat lately. The bigger question will be how to coordinate it :)

Comment: Well, I think we SHOULD restart the Fortnightly Topic Challenges.

Comment: @Lukas rotter, you will have the job of giving the candidate questions that join the competitions. I will give out the challenges.

Comment: If you've got @Stiv on-board, you know you'll get at least one quality puzzle. If you have an idea for a topic and are willing to do the legwork, I suggest you just send it. I'd rather spend time trying to write a puzzle than talking about whether I should be thinking about writing a puzzle.

Comment: Anonymus25, I think what @LukasRotter is offering is to coordinate the fortnightly posting of the challenge details and keep the posts updated with a list of the entries and any associated stats, which is a role he performed previously. In terms of assigning challenges, usually people post their suggestions on a specific thread and the community votes on which ones they would be keen to run with, with the highest-voted as-yet-unused idea becoming the next fortnight's challenge theme. I would propose following a similar scheme this time around as well.

Comment: Well, the next one will be all in @LukasRotter's hands. I just wanted to get things started, because now basically us three, we are the Fortnightly Challenge   Trio. ;)

Comment: Well, there are at least ten others (judging from the twelve upvotes) who may be interested :-)

Answer (score 2):

<s>19</s>, 20 upvotes!

---

It's clear that many people want the return of the Fortnightly Topic Challenges. We'll see if [@LukasRotter](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/37714/lukas-rotter) *does* continue the challenges, though I doubt that people will start ignoring this post.

###### Theme Proposals

Please edit this answer if you want to propose a theme if we *do* restart the Fortnightly Topic Challenges.

- It's been [proposed before](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6340/51105), so I'm just reiterating the motion here, but let's have a [reverse-puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reverse-puzzling) challenge. Previous fortnightly challenges on the topic have been [rather fruitful](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5Breverse-puzzling%5D%20fortnightly) and the [tag is still underutilized](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reverse-puzzling). - [@Taco タコス](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/51105/taco-%E3%82%BF%E3%82%B3%E3%82%B9)

Comment: I'm glad you're keen for this (I am too) but I should reiterate here what I said in chat on the 9th in response to @LukasRotter asking about when to call consensus on the new challenges being launched: "I'd say wait 'til the post is no longer 'Featured' in the sidebar - that gives it maximum time to get noticed on the main site. That'll be in just under 2 weeks. *Then* post the thread asking for [challenge] suggestions, with an aim of choosing the first one in time to begin on Sunday 1 November - start of a week AND start of a month, perfect!"

Comment: This way the challenge gets maximum publicity before it launches and hopefully more people will therefore get involved. Thanks for being an eager catalyst for moving things forwards but we should have an official community-wide post to launch the new series rather than tacking it on to this one, which I feel has served its purpose now of generating interest. Thanks :)

Comment: Because I live in Western Indonesia, your 1st November would be a different 1st november, because you're in the UK!

Comment: True, but the convention across the whole of the Stack Exchange network is [to use UTC](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42179/what-time-zone-do-sos-servers-operate-in) as a common reference (that's how a 'day' is marked out for the various [badges](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges) you can earn for doing particular activities on multiple days). So I expect that's what we'll run to, as we run everything else by it too :) (It's not a deliberate bias, it's just easiest for consistency...)

Comment: (Besides, a submission that's late by a few minutes is not going to get shot down in flames by the community - the times are just a guide. Think of it like the '[Pirate Code](https://pirates.fandom.com/wiki/Code_of_the_Pirate_Brethren)'!)

Comment: If it's worth anything: Yes I haven't changed my mind. I'm ready to start on Nov 1st

Comment: Alright! 19 more days!