# Fortnightly Topic Challenges Threrun: Topic Suggestions

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

**Fortnightly Topic Challenges are currently on hold**, due to the low activity that was unfortunately seen in the last few installments. They will be continued once enough popular suggestions are present again (or once enough users want FTCs to restart again). In the meanwhile, **you can still vote on and suggest** topics here, as they will still be used for the eventual restart.

---

[Let's](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7016/should-we-continue-the-fortnightly-topic-challenges) do fortnightly topic challenges [once](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/what-should-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges-be-with-updates) [again](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6339/fortnightly-topic-challenges-rerun)!

---

**What to Do**:

If you have an idea for a tag or a theme of any kind to use as a topic challenge, post it as an answer below. (Do note, you can propose anything, not only a tag). **Only one suggestion per answer, please.** [Here is a list of all tags, to help.](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tags)

**At the start of each fortnight, the highest-voted answer to this post will be selected as that fortnight's topic.** Starting from today, users can propose their themes or topics. The selected answer will then be deleted to reduce clutter in the list.

After the selection, a new question will be created in [this format](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4351/fortnightly-topic-challenge-1-movies). An answer will then be posted to that question with links to all the posts in the featured topic in the fortnight.

We'll again keep a list of all the topics.

Happy Puzzling!

### Current Topic:

- ***March 21st – April 3rd, 2021***
  **<kbd>Polyominoes</kbd>**
  <sub>suggested by **[Bubbler](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/71652)**</sub>

### Previous Topics:

- ***March 7th – March 20th, 2021***
  **<kbd>Non-rectangular grids</kbd>**
  <sub>suggested by **[Bubbler](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/71652)**</sub>
- ***February 21st – March 6th, 2021***
  **<kbd>Escape Rooms</kbd>**
  <sub>suggested by **[Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644)**</sub>
- ***February 7th – February 20th, 2021***
  **<kbd>Pub Quiz Camouflage</kbd>**
  <sub>suggested by **[Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644)**</sub>
- ***January 24th – February 6th, 2021***
  **<kbd>Unusual tag mix</kbd>**
  <sub>suggested by **[melfnt](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/63414)**</sub>
- ***January 10th – January 23rd, 2021***
  **<kbd>Wacky Sudokus</kbd>**
  <sub>suggested by **[Beastly Gerbil](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/18250)**</sub>
- ***December 27th – January 9th, 2021***
  **<kbd>"Tales From the Cryptic"</kbd>**
  <sub>suggested by **[Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644)**</sub>
- ***December 13th – December 26th, 2020***
  **<kbd>Flags</kbd>**
  <sub>suggested by **[Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644)**</sub>
- ***November 29th – December 12th, 2020***
  **<kbd>Introduce a new grid deduction genre to the community</kbd>**
  <sub>suggested by **[Bubbler](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/71652)**</sub>
- ***November 15th – November 28th, 2020***
  **<kbd>Variety Crossword Grids</kbd>**
  <sub>suggested by **[bobble](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/69582)**</sub>
- ***November 1st – November 14th, 2020***
  **<kbd>Wordless Connecting Walls</kbd>**
  <sub>suggested by **[Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644)**</sub>

Comment: A proposal: If/when all remaining answers don't have 5 or more upvotes, then that should be taken as a sign that proposals have run out and the series should (temporarily) stop once more

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil That might cause irregular voting from users who just want to keep the series alive, or even the opposite.

Answer (score 9):

*- Current Topic -*

---

### Polyominoes

[polyomino](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polyomino) often goes with other tags, such as

- [tiling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tiling), as in [Tiling with T-tetrominos in gravity](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/49665/71652)
- [combinatorics](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combinatorics) (which is also often combined with [tiling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tiling)), as in [L-tromino pair!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/101154/71652)
- [grid-deduction](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid-deduction) as a genre mashup, as in [Tetronogram](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/86652/71652) or [Tetromino minesweeper](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/102676/71652)
- sometimes [board-games](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/board-games), as in [What is the minimum-sized Blokus board which can contain all pieces?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/94835/71652)

but may also be a successful puzzle by itself, as in [Polyominoes to construct alphabet](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/95090/71652).

[Polyomino](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polyomino.html) is a long-time subject of recreational mathematics, and its properties can be used for grid deductions in many creative ways. So the challenge is to create a puzzle related to polyominoes in a creative way. Of course it does not need to be polyominoes made of squares; it can be [polyiamonds](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polyiamond.html) (made of triangles) or [polyhexes](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polyhex.html) (made of hexagons) too!

Answer (score 8):

### On-and-onograms

Create a puzzle where the first step is a [nonogram](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nonogram) whose solution reveals further steps that must be taken. Crucially, *the full puzzle is entirely self-contained within the nonogram and flavour text*. (i.e. Not just using a nonogram as the first step in a long string of grid-deduction puzzles which require additional grids to be displayed in the post.)

Good examples from the past include [these](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/84058/60644) [two](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/84266/60644) puzzles by @jafe, one of which conceals a [rebus](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rebus) and the other a set of [sequence](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence) puzzles.

Answer (score 8):

### Cellular Automata

Here's a regular tag that doesn't seem to get much love: [cellular-automata](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cellular-automata)

This can involve puzzles about a well-known cellular automaton, like for example [Conway's Game of Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life), or a cellular automaton you've created on your own!

Get creative! Maybe we need to reverse-engineer something, try to produce a certain output with given starting conditions, or something entirely different! Crossovers are of course allowed and encouraged.

Great examples of puzzles on this site are [Game of Life: Kill the Sun](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/31247/game-of-life-kill-the-sun), [Can you recreate this fractal I randomly made?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/43311/can-you-recreate-this-fractal-i-randomly-made) and [Checkerboard Infection](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/18074/checkerboard-infection)

Comment: I want to point out that [Wireworld](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireworld) is also an interesting cellular automaton ([awesome examples](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/88799/78410)). Given that Kill the Sun is a "complete this task in GoL" kind of puzzle, "complete this task in Wireworld" should work too.

Answer (score 7):

### Möbius Strips, Klein Bottles, and other unusual topological surfaces

[image]

Imagine an elastic square as above. If you ignore the red edges and glue the blue edges so that they have the same orientation, you get a [Möbius Strip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_strip). If you join both pairs of edges, you get a [Klein Bottle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_bottle). This is not the only interesting surface; you can have **12** different topologies in total by joining two pairs of edges of a square, which include:

[image] [image] [image]

(The last one is a plain torus.) The universal rule is that, if you're on the surface and you walk through an edge, you enter back to the grid through the matching edge with same orientation.

For example, consider this 4x4 grid:

```
A1 A2 A3 A4
B1 B2 B3 B4
C1 C2 C3 C4
D1 D2 D3 D4
```

Assume the Klein bottle topology at the top. If you're at B1 and walk left, you end up at B4 (by going through the red parallel edge). If you're at A2 and walk upwards, you end up at D3 (by going through the blue twisted edge).

For the first one on the second image set (the one where the matching edges are adjacent to each other), if you walk upwards from A1, you enter back at A1 but facing right!

The challenge is to create a puzzle that involves an unusual topological surface (which excludes plain wrap-around mechanic a.k.a. cylinder and torus). Such a puzzle may involve tiling, graph, crossword, or a grid-deduction genre, among others.

Some good examples:

- [A 4-D Cryptic Crossword](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/105224/71652)
- [HAISU with a twist](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/72147/71652)

You can search for puzzles containing [torus](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=torus), [toroidal](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=toroidal), or [wrap around](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=wrap+around) for some ideas.

<sub>There is even a programming language called [Klein](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Klein) that can run the same code on different topologies!</sub>

Answer (score 5):

#### Programming Puzzles

A programming puzzle most likely uses the tag [computer-science](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer-science) and/or [computer-puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer-puzzle) *(weird flex, but okay)*.

Programming is my passion, but sadly I'm not seeing much *(if any)* programming puzzles lately, python programming puzzles to be specific.
Yet most of the posts I do see tagged with [computer-puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer-puzzle) don't involve actual coding.

This challenge is to create a **good** [computer-science](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer-science) puzzle that requires a bit **more coding** and a little **less story-riddle stuff**. Stack Overflow is the biggest site on Stack Exchange, and it would be nice to be more welcoming to those users.

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you would consider a "good computer-science puzzle that requires a bit more coding and a little less story-riddle stuff"?

Comment: I generally agree, because I love programming and the idea of programming puzzles, but I feel they are really hard to properly pull off. Programing is more art than science, and there's pretty much never just one single answer. It's also really restrictive; the number of people who can reasonably solve a computer programming puzzle is really limited

Comment: @AnthonyIngram-Westover That why it's a challenge :)

Comment: @bobble Does this answer your question? https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7023/line-between-a-programming-puzzle-and-a-programming-problem

Comment: No, I have seen that, I would like a link to a main-site question you feel is a good one.

Comment: @bobble [This](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/65127/70545) is the only puzzle tagged [tag:computer-science] that isn't mine that even mentions python.

Comment: Also, that puzzle is not bad!

Answer (score 5):

### Game/Quiz Shows

> *This... is... Puzzling! Let's meet this fortnight's topic challengers...*

Create a puzzle themed around a real-life game or quiz show. The puzzle **must involve the basic format of the overall show in some way**, e.g. a *Jeopardy!*-themed puzzle might include answering trivia questions chosen from a board, while an [*Only Connect*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Only_Connect)-themed puzzle might include [sequence](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence) questions *and* a [connect-wall](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/connect-wall).

Some examples on this site, including the game/quiz shows they reference:

- [Let's spin the wheel!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/24661/57742) - *Wheel of Fortune*
- The [Slumdog millionaire](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/11226/57742) series - *Who Wants to Be a Millionaire?*
- [Can I have a 'P' please, Bob?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/107757/57742) - [*Blockbusters*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blockbusters_(American_game_show)) (this is what inspired me to come up with this FTC proposal)

And Wikipedia has ["Lists of game shows"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_game_shows) from a variety of countries, linked here for informational and inspirational purposes.

**Notes:**

- Puzzles that are dressed up as or reference game/quiz shows but do not directly involve the format of a real-life show *are not eligible* for this challenge, e.g. the [Monty Hall problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Hall_problem), a standalone [connect-wall](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/connect-wall)
- Puzzles asking about *optimal strategies* for playing game/quiz shows *are eligible*, as long as what the "best" strategy is can be objectively quantified, e.g. [Monopoly Game Show: Is there a winning strategy?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/19848/57742)

Comment: Let me know if any of the requirements are confusing - I'll admit, some of these rules and examples may be a bit contradictory, but I'm not sure how to clearly state my intent with this proposal yet

Answer (score 4):

**Logic Around the World**

Quite simply, use a combination of the [logical-deduction](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logical-deduction) tag and the [geography](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geography) tag. [This](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/99271/farewell-barry-poppins) puzzle and [this one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/74041/coffee-and-a-movie-with-friends) are great examples. The only rules are that they must contain BOTH of these tags!

Answer (score 3):

**Twisted Chess**

I've seen many chess puzzles where it is a variant of chess, and not about chess itself. So, the goal of this challenge is to do just that! It can be a new piece, a new variant, an existing variant, anything! (Just not using the rules of regular chess.) The puzzle goal can be a mate in 1, a winning position, or an optimization puzzle. Your only limit is your imagination!

Answer (score 3):

**Metapuzzles**

I enjoy reading the solutions to metapuzzles, they always are interesting. Deusovi's old Chess Fortnight puzzle is one great example. Metapuzzles could be stuffed into one question, or spread out in a series with a final puzzle that ties all the previous ones together.

Answer (score 2):

**Puzzles about Stack Exchange**

There are a few puzzles which topic regards the scoring mechanism, the privilege system, the users, the ids of the posts or other features of stack exchange. Here are some of my favorites:

- [PSE Assessment Exam](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/49621/pse-assessment-exam)
- [Liar Puzzle with Stack Exchange Users](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/15524/liar-puzzle-with-stack-exchange-users)
- [Yet another number sequence puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47601/yet-another-number-sequence-puzzle)
- [All the moderators have been kidnapped!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/52602/all-the-moderators-have-been-kidnapped)

My proposal for this challenge is to create more puzzles like these. They can be about Puzzling Stack Exchange or Stack Exchange in general. Please read this before creating such puzzles: [Riddles involving Stack Exchange: Off topic?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6833/riddles-involving-stack-exchange-off-topic)

Comment: I'm not sure this is a good idea - it seems like it will lend itself only to using information that may change over time, which doesn't make for a long-lasting puzzle. (And if you refer to specific users, apart from the problem of "the users may leave, making the puzzle unsolvable" there's also the fact that many people don't like having their names used in puzzles.)

Comment: (Echoing Deusovi's comment: we have [guidelines](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1690/69582) about using people's names in puzzles))

Comment: @Deusovi I linked a meta question which has an answer in which you state that *"Questions involving Stack Exchange are fine, but you should take care to note that they're solvable long after they're posted"*. I agree with your answer and I don't see what's wrong in posting a puzzle that fit that guidelines

Comment: @bobble I know, I wasn't referring to posting puzzles with someone's name on them. Also, many of these puzzles are not about SE, they just use the usernnames

Comment: Will a puzzle that mentions PSE users as Among Us players count?

Comment: @Anonymus25-ReinstateMonica no. I want you to create puzzles about the stackexchange **mechanisms**, not just to use the usernames in an arbitrary puzzle. Also, you should be careful when using the other people's username in a puzzle: see bobble's answer above.

Answer (score 2):

#### Sinister Stories in Casual Concepts

A puzzle, most likely tagged with [mystery](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mystery) or [riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/riddle), where the theme is dark and sinister, and it's the solver's task to find out what common object or situation the puzzle is hinting at.

Some great examples are:

- [A loving marriage?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/60844/70545)
- [If you don't care for me, I will hurt you. Who am I?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/23588/70545)

And an example I made:

- [Ever notice those dangerous hollow eyes staring at you?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/105065/70545)

Answer (score 2):

### A previous Puzzle (part 2)

A puzzle based on a previous puzzle posted on PSE by another user and that is not already part of a series: it could be the same game with a slight variation in the rules, it could be the same [grid-deduction](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid-deduction) puzzle with a different schema or just a continuation of the story in the previous puzzle.

There are many examples of this kind of puzzles, but they are a bit difficult to find. The only one I can think of is [Prime Number Snake](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/93030/prime-number-snake), posted by @BernardoRecamánSantos and [Prime number snake (2)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/93116/prime-number-snake-2), posted by @daw.

Answer (score 1):

### The Puzzles Around Us

Sometimes you are wondering: why [the keyboard of your friend is very strange](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/63326/28719), how to [change your baby's shirt while they're still drinking their milk](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/61522/28719), or what is [the best strategy to go to the campus while also refilling your bottle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/64728/28719).

Undoubtedly as human, we think and reason a lot. Tackling [real](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real)-life problems will be more fun and fulfilling if we consider them as puzzles!