# Fortnightly Topic Challenge #42: Wordless Connecting Walls

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This is the first installment of the Fortnightly Topic Challenges Rerun described [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2841) and the forty-second installment of the FTCs overall, with topics suggested and voted on [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7032). This fortnight's topic is ***"Wordless Connecting Walls"*** (suggested by [Stiv](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/60644)) and will span from the **1st of November to the 14th of November**. During this period, we will compile the list of relevant questions and post it as an answer to this question.

**In the meantime, please go and [propose and vote on future challenges!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7032)**

Everyone have fun, and happy puzzling!

<sub>*Link to [other](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20title%3a%22Fortnightly%20Topic%20Challenge%20%23) Fortnightly Topic Challenges.*</sub>

***NOTE***
The suggestion is copied to this post for posterity.

> ### Wordless Connecting Walls
>
> A [connect-wall](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/connect-wall) puzzle most often involves partitioning 16 words into 4 categories, often with a final connection between the 4 categories too. However, in the past we have seen impressive connecting walls that break this mould, instead using (e.g.) [sheet music](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/90828/60644), [cryptic clues](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/40819/60644), [missing vowel puzzles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/89873/60644) and even [computer code](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/67546/60644)!
>
> This challenge would be to create a [connect-wall](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/connect-wall) puzzle which breaks the usual mould and presents its 16 connecting components in an interesting or creative alternative way, not simply as 16 individual words.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**List of all questions published as part of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge #42:**

- [Connecting Sixteen Shades](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/104417) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644)
- [Visual Connect Wall: Heads up!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/104432/) by [Sciborg](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/53621)
- [Connect Wall of Flags: Don't Embarrass Us](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/104433/) by [bobble](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/69582)
- [Hanging on the Connect Wall](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/104441/) by [Jeremy Dover](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/69217)
- [What are these holes in my Connect Wall?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/104458/) by [Ankoganit](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/25412/ankoganit)
- [Connect Wall: "Who's that Pokémon?"](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/104466/) by [Prince North Læraðr](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/45158)
- [Connect Wall - Grid Puzzles Edition!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/104498/) by [athin](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/28719)
- [History is written by the Connect Wall](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/104512/) by [Jeremy Dover](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/69217)
- [Yes, this is the legendary wall](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/104556/) by [Ankoganit](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/25412)
- [Sergeant Sequence calls for back-up](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/104593/) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644)
- [Please Don't Flag This Question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/104609/) by [Prince North Læraðr](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/45158)
- [Kicking and screaming (a musical connect wall)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/104669/) by [JS1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/4479)
- [Connect Wall of Flags: Stimulants are Endless!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/104672/) by [bobble](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/69582)
- [You're given the following list of numbers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/104471/) by [Glorfindel](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/11110)
- [Re-Venn-ge of the Connecting Wall](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/104752/) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644)
- [Sports Connect Wall](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/104775/) by [JKHA](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/51928)
- [Shingoki: An Exploration of Unicode](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/104786/) by [oAlt](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/61669)
- [A Connect Wall to Fly Over](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/104820/) by [hexomino](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/18422)
- *add further entries in the form
  `https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/<question-ID> by [username](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)`*

---

The **highest-voted** three of these are:

- [Re-Venn-ge of the Connecting Wall](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/104752) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644), with a score of **29** at the end of the fortnight.
- [Yes, this is the legendary wall](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/104556) by [Ankoganit](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/25412), with a score of **26** at the end of the fortnight.
- [Hanging on the Connect Wall](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/104441) by [Jeremy Dover](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/69217), with a score of **17** at the end of the fortnight.

The **most viewed** three of these are:

- [Yes, this is the legendary wall](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/104556) by [Ankoganit](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/25412), with **1748** views at the end of the fortnight.
- [Connect Wall: "Who's that Pokémon?"](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/104466) by [Prince North Læraðr](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/45158), with **1504** views at the end of the fortnight.
- [Connect Wall of Flags: Don't Embarrass Us](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/104433) by [bobble](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/69582), with **622** views at the end of the fortnight.

Comment: Actually I already had my musical connect wall planned out (since about 6 months ago), but ever since Covid started I haven't had the time/motivation to finish writing the puzzle.  Then I saw the Fortnightly Topic Challenge which happened to fit the puzzle exactly, and it gave me the push I needed to finally complete it.

Comment: People might be interested to know that the latest [tag:connect-wall] puzzle took us to 100 total on the site and opened up the [bronze connect-wall tag badge](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/badges/166/connect-wall)!

Comment: @Stiv ... except that having 100 questions with a tag is not quite related to allowing a tag badge. Congratulations for the badge btw.

Comment: @Bubbler Are you sure about that? Because I had 25 eligible answers prior to this and the badge was awarded within a couple of hours of the 100th question with this tag going live...? I was under the impression tags didn't qualify for badges until there were enough questions using them...

Comment: @Stiv Ooh, just googled it and [it indeed requires 100 questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/1721/419414). Then it deserves double congrats!