# Fortnightly Topic Challenge #43: Variety Crossword Grids

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This is the second installment of the Fortnightly Topic Challenges Rerun described [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2841) and the forty-third installment of the FTCs overall, with topics suggested and voted on [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7032). This fortnight's topic is ***"Variety Crossword Grids"*** (suggested by [bobble](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/69582)) and will span from the **15th of November to the 28th of November**. During this period, we will compile the list of relevant questions and post it as an answer to this question.

**In the meantime, please go and [propose and vote on future challenges!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7032)**

Everyone have fun, and happy puzzling!

<sub>*Link to [other](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20title%3a%22Fortnightly%20Topic%20Challenge%20%23) Fortnightly Topic Challenges.*</sub>

***NOTE***
The suggestion is copied to this post for posterity.

> ### Variety Crossword Grids
>
> Normal crosswords has the entries go right-to-left and top-to-bottom, one letter per cell. Bah! That's too simple. The challenge here is to make a variety crossword where the words go in different directions and/or have variable letters per cell. Some ideas:
>
> - Words that go diagonally
> - Words that go "backwards" (left-to-right or bottom-to-top) in a grid with words that also go "forwards"
> - Words that go in circles
> - Words that don't go in straight lines
> - A grid where each cell contains 1, 2, or 3 letters.
> - A grid with triangular or hexagonal cells.
>
> Examples of what I would consider variety grids are [Around the Bend](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98628/around-the-bend) and [Marching Bands](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/100342/rows-circles-wordplay-and-semi-obscure-cultural-references-a-crossword) crosswords.
>
> The actual words and clues can be completely normal - or they can be "variety" as well. Just the grids have to be variety. Feel free to use currently-existing variety crossword types or make up your own.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**List of all questions published as part of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge #43:**

- [Gladys's Gapped Cryptic](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/104852) by [jafe](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/41973)
- [Self-contained math crossword with if-then-else clues](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/104964) by [melfnt](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/63414)
- [3D cryptic brain melter](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105051) by [jafe](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/41973)
- [A Cryptic Hourglass](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105059) by [Jeremy Dover](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/69217)
- [A Tribute to Psych](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105063) by [JS1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/4479)
- [Animal Cross(word)ing](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105113) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644)
- [Six Directions of Cryptic Cluebulence](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105134) by [jafe](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/41973)
- [This ain't your grandpa's word square!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105164) by [bobble](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/69582)
- [Coming back with a 4D Crossword!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105183) by [Omega Krypton](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/51131)
- [Stacking word bouncer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105210) by [Retudin](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/71170)
- [Another Straightforward 4-letters Crossword?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105216) by [athin](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/28719)
- [A 4-D Cryptic Crossword](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105224/a-4-d-cryptic-crossword) by [Jeremy Dover](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/69217)
- *add further entries in the form
  `https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/<question-ID> by [username](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)`*

---

The **highest-voted** three of these are:

- [Animal Cross(word)ing](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105113) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644), with a score of **36** at the end of the fortnight.
- [Self-contained math crossword with if-then-else clues](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/104964) by [melfnt](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/63414), with a score of **32** at the end of the fortnight.
- [This ain't your grandpa's word square!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105164) by [bobble](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/69582), with a score of **21** at the end of the fortnight.

The **most viewed** three of these are:

- [Animal Cross(word)ing](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105113) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644), with **1836** views at the end of the fortnight.
- [Self-contained math crossword with if-then-else clues](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/104964) by [melfnt](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/63414), with **1021** views at the end of the fortnight.
- [This ain't your grandpa's word square!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105164) by [bobble](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/69582), with **698** views at the end of the fortnight.

Answer (score 3):

Is this puzzle a good candidate for this challenge?

[Self-contained math crossword with if-then-else clues](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/104964/self-contained-math-crossword-with-if-then-else-clues)

The grid has no variety of any sort but the circular clues and the if-then-else clues are definitely strange.

Comment: I would say so - you use numbers instead of letters and the clues are entirely self-referential. There's very little standard about that! The grid may be square in shape but I would say there are enough elements out of the ordinary here to count as 'variety'...