# Monthly Topic Challenge #4: Cross-*non*-words

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This is the fourth installment of the Monthly Topic Challenges with topics suggested and voted on [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7265). This month's topic is ***"Cross-*non*-words"*** (suggested by [Stiv](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/60644)) and will span from the **1st of October to the 31st of October**. During this period, we will compile the list of relevant questions and post it as an answer to this question.

**In the meantime, please go and [propose and vote on future challenges!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7265)**

Everyone have fun, and happy puzzling!

<sub>*Link to [other](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20title%3a%22Monthly%20Topic%20Challenge%20%23) Monthly Topic Challenges.*</sub>

***NOTE***
The suggestion is copied to this post for posterity.

> ### Cross-*non*-words
>
> The challenge here is to produce a crossword wherein some (or all) squares are filled not with typical English alphabet characters, but with something else altogether.
>
> Such a crossword might contain no English alphabet characters at all (e.g. each square instead contains an image, a special character, a number, etc.) or each answer within it features at least one square containing one such alternative... Crucially, **no words in the grid should appear *fully* spelled out with English alphabet characters**.
>
> <sub>*Note:* This is *not* merely a repeat of [FTC #43: Variety Crossword Grids](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7062/60644) from November 2020 - here it is **the content of the squares** wherein the variety lies, as opposed to the structure of the grid...</sub>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**List of all questions published as part of the Monthly Topic Challenge #4:**

| Puzzle | Creator |
| --- | --- |
| [There are 10 types 0f pe0ple 1n the w0rld](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/118165/there-are-10-types-0f-pe0ple-1n-the-w0rld) | [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644/stiv) |
| [T9 Crossword Puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/118170/t9-crossword-puzzle) | [sarsaparilla](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60396/sarsaparilla) |
| [Are you getting tired of regular crosswords?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/118326/are-you-getting-tired-of-regular-crosswords) | [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644/stiv) |
| [Neo-Futurist Poetry](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/118351/neo-futurist-poetry) | [Parcly Taxel](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/75318/parcly-taxel) |
| [What does the neo-futurist poetry mean?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/118394/what-does-the-neo-futurist-poetry-mean) | [Scratch---Cat](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/54367/scratch-cat) |
| [Crossword by name, crossword by nature](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/118505/crossword-by-name-crossword-by-nature) | [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644/stiv) |
| [The woefully underclued crossword](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/118515/the-woefully-underclued-crossword) | [Jafe](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/41973/jafe) |
| [Hexagonal Topline Crossword](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/118516/hexagonal-topline-crossword) | [Scratch---Cat](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/54367/scratch-cat) |
| [A 2x2 Crossword](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/118520/a-2x2-crossword) | [WoomyRogue](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/75335/woomyrogue) |
| [Gathering for fraternities and sororities](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/118564/gathering-for-fraternities-and-sororities) | [Scratch---Cat](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/54367/scratch-cat) |

---

The **highest-voted** three of these are:

- [Are you getting tired of regular crosswords?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/118326) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644), with a score of **28** at the end of the month.
- [The woefully underclued crossword](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/118515) by [Jafe](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/41973), with a score of **23** at the end of the month.
- [Neo-Futurist Poetry](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/118351) by [Parcly Taxel](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/75318), with a score of **14** at the end of the month.

The **most viewed** three of these are:

- [Are you getting tired of regular crosswords?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/118326) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644), with **1478** views at the end of the month.
- [The woefully underclued crossword](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/118515) by [Jafe](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/41973), with **1119** views at the end of the month.
- [There are 10 types 0f pe0ple 1n the w0rld](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/118165) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644), with **927** views at the end of the month.