# Fortnightly Topic Challenge #45: Flags

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This is the fourth installment of the Fortnightly Topic Challenges Rerun described [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2841) and the forty-fifth installment of the FTCs overall, with topics suggested and voted on [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7032). This fortnight's topic is ***"Flags"*** (suggested by [Stiv](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/60644)) and will span from the **13th of December to the 26th of December**. During this period, we will compile the list of relevant questions and post it as an answer to this question.

**In the meantime, please go and [propose and vote on future challenges!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7032)**

Everyone have fun, and happy puzzling!

<sub>*Link to [other](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20title%3a%22Fortnightly%20Topic%20Challenge%20%23) Fortnightly Topic Challenges.*</sub>

***NOTE***
The suggestion is copied to this post for posterity.

> ### Flags
>
> Quite simply, questions which use the [flags](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flags) tag (one of my favourites), which didn't get a run out in either of the last two FTC runs.
>
> Take your pick from the usual [geography](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geography) candidates, nautical codes, semaphore, or any others you can think of!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**List of all questions published as part of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge #45:**

- [Enigmatic flags mashup](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105678) by [melfnt](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/63414)
- [A flag-packing problem](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105707) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644)
- ["I claim this corner of the world for Britain!" - What game are Alex and Brooke playing?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105741) by [bobble](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/69582)
- [Flagging Interest](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105826) by [Jeremy Dover](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/69217)
- [Embassy Park - A Grid Deduction Puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105920) by [Jeremy Dover](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/69217)
- [Captain Clumsy's crummy communication](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105954) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644)
- [Cheesemonger's puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106008) by [Mariia Mykhailova](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/51753)
- [On a budget with my travel agent](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106043) by [Jeremy Dover](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/69217)
- *add further entries in the form
  `https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/<question-ID> by [username](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)`*

---

The **highest-voted** three of these are:

- ["I claim this corner of the world for Britain!" - What game are Alex and Brooke playing?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105741) by [bobble](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/69582), with a score of **35** at the end of the fortnight.
- [A flag-packing problem](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105707) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644), with a score of **29** at the end of the fortnight.
- [Enigmatic flags mashup](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105678) by [melfnt](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/63414), with a score of **15** at the end of the fortnight.

The **most viewed** three of these are:

- ["I claim this corner of the world for Britain!" - What game are Alex and Brooke playing?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105741) by [bobble](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/69582), with **1892** views at the end of the fortnight.
- [A flag-packing problem](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105707) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644), with **775** views at the end of the fortnight.
- [Enigmatic flags mashup](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105678) by [melfnt](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/63414), with **476** views at the end of the fortnight.