# Fortnightly Topic Challenge #46: "Tales From the Cryptic"

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This is the fifth installment of the Fortnightly Topic Challenges Rerun described [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2841) and the forty-sixth installment of the FTCs overall, with topics suggested and voted on [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7032). This fortnight's topic is ***""Tales From the Cryptic""*** (suggested by [Stiv](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/60644)) and will span from the **27th of December to the 9th of January**. During this period, we will compile the list of relevant questions and post it as an answer to this question.

**In the meantime, please go and [propose and vote on future challenges!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7032)**

Everyone have fun, and happy puzzling!

<sub>*Link to [other](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20title%3a%22Fortnightly%20Topic%20Challenge%20%23) Fortnightly Topic Challenges.*</sub>

***NOTE***
The suggestion is copied to this post for posterity.

> ### "Tales From the Cryptic"
>
> I can't see any trace in past FTC's of [cryptic-crosswords](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptic-crosswords) or [cryptic-clues](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptic-clues) being used (or even suggested) as a theme, so I reckon its about time...
>
> Specifically, this suggestion is a recommendation for combining one of these two cryptic tags with the [story](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story) tag, and making use of cryptic clues (or a full crossword) within a specific setting or further context (for example, as many of @jafe's more recent ['Gladys' puzzles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=gladys%20user%3ajafe) have done very ably).
>
> If the Cryptic Clue Chat Chains (CCCC) in [The Sphinx's Lair](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14524/the-sphinxs-lair) chatroom are any indication, we have a flourishing group of very able (or at least very up-for-it!) setters and solvers hungry for cryptics - this should give them something to get their teeth into!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**List of all questions published as part of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge #46:**

- [A Cryptic Tale Indeed!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106132) by [Dmihawk](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/34793)
- [Detective Dad is on the case!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106167) by [jafe](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/41973)
- [A Cryptic Morality Tale](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106226) by [Jeremy Dover](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/69217)
- [Not Bluebeard's Castle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106294) by [Deusovi](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/11876)
- [The Maze of Hermes](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106306) by [Graylocke](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/33242)
- [Oops! All Acros--](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106344) by [Deusovi](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/11876)
- [In Any Case...](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106402) by [Deusovi](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/11876)
- [Shipwreck hunting](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106406) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644)
- *add further entries in the form
  `https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/<question-ID> by [username](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)`*

---

The **highest-voted** three of these are:

- [A Cryptic Tale Indeed!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106132) by [Dmihawk](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/34793), with a score of **18** at the end of the fortnight.
- [Not Bluebeard's Castle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106294) by [Deusovi](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/11876), with a score of **17** at the end of the fortnight.
- [In Any Case... : a cryptic crossword](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106402) by [Deusovi](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/11876), with a score of **15** at the end of the fortnight.

The **most viewed** three of these are:

- [Oops! All Acros--](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106344) by [Deusovi](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/11876), with **637** views at the end of the fortnight.
- [A Cryptic Tale Indeed!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106132) by [Dmihawk](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/34793), with **394** views at the end of the fortnight.
- [Not Bluebeard's Castle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106294) by [Deusovi](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/11876), with **333** views at the end of the fortnight.