# Fortnightly Topic Challenge #47: Wacky Sudokus

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This is the sixth installment of the Fortnightly Topic Challenges Rerun described [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2841) and the forty-seventh installment of the FTCs overall, with topics suggested and voted on [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7032). This fortnight's topic is ***"Wacky Sudokus"*** (suggested by [Beastly Gerbil](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/18250)) and will span from the **10th of January to the 23rd of January**. During this period, we will compile the list of relevant questions and post it as an answer to this question.

**In the meantime, please go and [propose and vote on future challenges!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7032)**

Everyone have fun, and happy puzzling!

<sub>*Link to [other](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20title%3a%22Fortnightly%20Topic%20Challenge%20%23) Fortnightly Topic Challenges.*</sub>

***NOTE***
The suggestion is copied to this post for posterity.

> ### Wacky Sudokus
>
> In case you can't tell, weird [sudoku](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sudoku) variants are a personal favourite of mine. They have both been very enjoyable to make, but also rewarding in seeing the feedback and interest received.
>
> I know a lot of people on this site are fans of the youtube channel Cracking the Cryptic, where many such wacky sudokus have been seen before
>
> Wacky sudokus are sudokus that use rules or concepts that have yet to be seen before, or are very uncommon. They can pretty much involve anything, as long as it is not a normal sudoku.
>
> Here are some examples of such wacky sudokus:
>
> - [Sudoku like you've never seen it before](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/100910/sudoku-like-youve-never-seen-it-before)
> - [Self-referential Sudoku](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/12208/self-referential-sudoku)
> - [Ever heard of a W-Sudoku?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/104167/ever-heard-of-a-w-sudoku)
> - [Sudoku in the third dimension (3D Sudoku)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/101257/sudoku-in-the-third-dimension-3d-sudoku)
>
> I think this would be a fun topic to see what the community can come up with!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**List of all questions published as part of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge #47:**

- Beastly Gerbil's Sudoku Series: [Blind Killer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106461/the-blind-killer-a-new-series-ss1), [Trinary](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106499/1-2-3-trinary-ss2), [Shattered Web](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106527/shattered-webs-ss3), [Odd Ones](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106555/this-is-an-odd-sudoku-ss4), [Parquet Square](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106597/a-mosaic-sudoku-ss5), [0-9](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106625/sudoku-with-10-digits-ss6), [Sandwiched](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106652/a-scrumptious-sudoku-sandwich-ss7), [Min Max](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106670/a-difficult-wacky-sudoku-ss8), [Suguru](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106689/a-7x7-suguru-ss9), [Skyscrapers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106722/skyscrapers-in-sudoku-ss10), [Staircase](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106771/this-sudoku-takes-a-step-up-ss11), [Boxless Pseudoku](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106803/sudoku-with-no-grid-and-no-numbers-ss12), [Fractal](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106831/a-fractal-sudoku-ss13), [Digital](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106848/a-final-digitial-sudoku-ss14)
- [Compoundoku wants REALLY BIG and WACKY!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106611) by [athin](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/28719)
- [The Blank Sudoku](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106676) by [Jeremy Dover](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/69217)
- [A Puzzling Sudoku (Warning: Hot!)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106691) by [Lukas Rotter](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/37714)
- [Didn't you ask me for a crossword?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106725) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644)
- [Sudoku in Technicolor!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106798) by [Jeremy Dover](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/69217)
- [Sudoku: Odd Bonds](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106840) by [oAlt](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/61669)
- [This Sudoku Park iS LIT!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106843) by [Jeremy Dover](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/69217)
- *add further entries in the form
  `https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/<question-ID> by [username](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)`*

---

The **highest-voted** three of these are:

- [Didn't you ask me for a crossword?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106725) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644), with a score of **37** at the end of the fortnight.
- [The Blank Sudoku](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106676) by [Jeremy Dover](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/69217), with a score of **25** at the end of the fortnight.
- [A Puzzling Sudoku (Warning: Hot!)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106691) by [Lukas Rotter](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/37714), with a score of **24** at the end of the fortnight.

The **most viewed** three of these are:

- [The Blank Sudoku](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106676) by [Jeremy Dover](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/69217), with **1392** views at the end of the fortnight.
- [A Puzzling Sudoku (Warning: Hot!)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106691) by [Lukas Rotter](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/37714), with **1220** views at the end of the fortnight.
- [Didn't you ask me for a crossword?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106725) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644), with **1051** views at the end of the fortnight.

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil I think you have to write one question per line so that the bot can parse this answer automatically to extract the most most viewed and highest-voted questions at the end of the fortnight. Actually I'm not so sure this is done automatically, but if it is you'll have to respect the given format.

Comment: @melfnt I've asked Lukas Rotter about it, and he said it should still work like this! I'm only entering it like this so the answer isn't take up solely by my puzzles :)

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil ok then, I'll leave these comments in case someone else wonders