# Fortnightly Topic Challenge #49: Pub Quiz Camouflage

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This is the eighth installment of the Fortnightly Topic Challenges Rerun described [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2841) and the forty-ninth installment of the FTCs overall, with topics suggested and voted on [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7032). This fortnight's topic is ***"Pub Quiz Camouflage"*** (suggested by [Stiv](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/60644)) and will span from the **7th of February to the 20th of February**. During this period, we will compile the list of relevant questions and post it as an answer to this question.

**In the meantime, please go and [propose and vote on future challenges!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7032)**

Everyone have fun, and happy puzzling!

<sub>*Link to [other](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20title%3a%22Fortnightly%20Topic%20Challenge%20%23) Fortnightly Topic Challenges.*</sub>

***NOTE***
The suggestion is copied to this post for posterity.

> ### Pub Quiz Camouflage
>
> The [pub quiz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pub_quiz) is a staple form of entertainment in British culture, usually involving teams of patrons in a pub or bar competing against each other to answer trivia questions. Sometimes the rounds have clever hidden themes for which bonus points can be awarded (e.g. spot the connection between all of the answers...).
>
> This challenge would use the concept of a pub quiz as its foundation, involving a set of [knowledge](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/knowledge) questions (with allowance for even more specific trivia themes on this site like [movies](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movies), [chemistry](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chemistry) or [literature](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/literature), for example). However, the twist is that there is *another sub-puzzle to the quiz*, dependent either on its answers, its layout/presentation, or the wording of its questions. However it is concealed, there is more to this quiz than meets the eye!
>
> <sub>A straight-out quiz would not be the style of Puzzling.SE - but a quiz with a puzzly twist?? Surely!</sub>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**List of all questions published as part of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge #49:**

- [Sergeant Sequence dodges a bullet](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/107199/) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644/stiv)
- [What was I supposed to do?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/107251/) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644/stiv)
- [Bar trivia is heating up](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/107284) by [Jeremy Dover](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/69217)
- [The Heart of the Matter, a Sergeant Sequence mystery (fan-fic)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/107299) by [Jeremy Dover](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/69217)
- [Trivia... sudoku](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/107317/trivia-sudoku) by [melfnt](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/63414/melfnt)
- [A Pub Quiz Joke](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/107435/a-pub-quiz-joke) by [oAlt](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/61669/oalt)
- *add further entries in the form
  `https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/<question-ID> by [username](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)`*

---

The **highest-voted** three of these are:

- [What was I supposed to do?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/107251) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644), with a score of **47** at the end of the fortnight.
- [Bar trivia is heating up](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/107284) by [Jeremy Dover](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/69217), with a score of **18** at the end of the fortnight.
- [Sergeant Sequence dodges a bullet](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/107199) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644), with a score of **14** at the end of the fortnight.

The **most viewed** three of these are:

- [What was I supposed to do?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/107251) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644), with **3859** views at the end of the fortnight.
- [Bar trivia is heating up](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/107284) by [Jeremy Dover](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/69217), with **463** views at the end of the fortnight.
- [Sergeant Sequence dodges a bullet](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/107199) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644), with **390** views at the end of the fortnight.