# Fortnightly Topic Challenge #50: Escape Rooms

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This is the ninth installment of the Fortnightly Topic Challenges Rerun described [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2841) and the fiftieth installment of the FTCs overall, with topics suggested and voted on [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7032). This fortnight's topic is ***"Escape Rooms"*** (suggested by [Stiv](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/60644)) and will span from the **21st of February to the 6th of March**. During this period, we will compile the list of relevant questions and post it as an answer to this question.

**In the meantime, please go and [propose and vote on future challenges!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7032)**

Everyone have fun, and happy puzzling!

<sub>*Link to [other](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20title%3a%22Fortnightly%20Topic%20Challenge%20%23) Fortnightly Topic Challenges.*</sub>

***NOTE***
The suggestion is copied to this post for posterity.

> ### Escape Rooms
>
> In (what I am here terming) an 'Escape Room' puzzle, the solver is presented with several seemingly disparate pieces of information in the form of sub-puzzles whose interconnections may not immediately be apparent at first glance. Usually the aim of the overall puzzle is to solve each sub-puzzle, finding their interconnections along the way, and ultimately identify a specific piece of information that enables the scenario to be 'escaped' - e.g. a passcode to pass through a door, or a location where somebody or something might be found.
>
> Crucially, all sub-puzzles are necessary (or at least provide additional hints) for finding the end solution - red herrings are rarely welcome, and extraneous sub-puzzles with no apparent bearing on the solution path are a waste of time for which the setter would not be thanked.
>
> There have been several hugely impressive 'escape room' type puzzles on PSE in the past, perhaps most notably:
>
> - [This is important. I need you to listen…](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/28494) by [Alconja](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5208/alconja)
> - [You have prepared. You are determined. You approach the door](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/31557) by [Alconja](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5208/alconja)
> - [This is it. This is the one. Find your wife](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/36256) by [Beastly Gerbil](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/18250/beastly-gerbil)
>
> As the mammoth upvote counts on these examples show, when this type of puzzle is done well it tends to be incredibly well-received and appreciated by the community (people love these!) - however, recently we have seen new Escape Room puzzles only very rarely. While I appreciate that this is partly because such a puzzle often requires a large investment of time and imagination to prepare and create, making this an FTC topic would present the perfect opportunity for PSE-ers to show their ingenuity and try something new and exciting - and there is nothing to stop puzzle setters getting started on creating their Escape Room puzzle ahead of time to get a headstart on the fortnight!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**List of all questions published as part of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge #50:**

- [28 Minutes Later](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/107521/) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644/)
- [Should You Take the Pill?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/107586/) by [Amoz](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/70710/)
- [The Puzzling Free-to-Play Escape Room, naturally!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/107593/) by [samm82](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/50054)
- [Escape from Sudoku!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/107607) by [JeremyDover](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/69217)
- [This escape room sucked! Did I do something wrong?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/107699/57742) by [HTM](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/57742)
- *add further entries in the form
  `https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/<question-ID> by [username](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)`*

---

The **highest-voted** three of these are:

- [28 Minutes Later](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/107521) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644), with a score of **54** at the end of the fortnight.
- [Escape from Sudoku!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/107607) by [Jeremy Dover](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/69217), with a score of **19** at the end of the fortnight.
- [Should You Take the Pill?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/107586) by [Amoz](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/70710), with a score of **18** at the end of the fortnight.

The **most viewed** three of these are:

- [28 Minutes Later](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/107521) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644), with **2578** views at the end of the fortnight.
- [Escape from Sudoku!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/107607) by [Jeremy Dover](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/69217), with **314** views at the end of the fortnight.
- [Should You Take the Pill?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/107586) by [Amoz](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/70710), with **293** views at the end of the fortnight.