# Fortnightly Topic Challenge #51: Non-rectangular grids

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This is the tenth installment of the Fortnightly Topic Challenges Rerun described [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2841) and the fifty-first installment of the FTCs overall, with topics suggested and voted on [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7032). This fortnight's topic is ***"Non-rectangular grids"*** (suggested by [Bubbler](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/71652)) and will span from the **7th of March to the 20th of March**. During this period, we will compile the list of relevant questions and post it as an answer to this question.

**In the meantime, please go and [propose and vote on future challenges!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7032)**

Everyone have fun, and happy puzzling!

<sub>*Link to [other](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20title%3a%22Fortnightly%20Topic%20Challenge%20%23) Fortnightly Topic Challenges.*</sub>

***NOTE***
The suggestion is copied to this post for posterity.

> ### Non-rectangular grids
>
> Create a puzzle that acts on any kind of non-rectangular grids. The grid can be simple triangular or hexagonal grids, but be creative: there are [so many different plane tilings using regular polygons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_tilings_by_convex_regular_polygons), and you can even use non-regular ones!
>
> Excellent examples include [Octagonal Kurotto](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/90528/71652) and [Karst - a variant of Cave](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/51994/71652). [Cryptic hourglass](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/105059/71652) is also a notable example of (essentially hexagonal) grid applied to a crossword in a non-traditional way (the words can bend in the middle).
>
> Personally inspired by [snub square tiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snub_square_tiling), whose dual circle packing has an interesting property that all circles touch with exactly five other circles:
>
> [image] [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**List of all questions published as part of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge #51:**

- [Can I have a 'P' please, Bob?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/107757/) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644/)
- [Tapa on a Penrose Tiling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/107892) by [JeremyDover](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/69217)
- *add further entries in the form
  `https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/<question-ID> by [username](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)`*