# Fortnightly Topic Challenge #52: Polyominoes

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This is the twelfth installment of the Fortnightly Topic Challenges Rerun described [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2841) and the fifty-second installment of the FTCs overall, with topics suggested and voted on [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7032). This fortnight's topic is ***"Polyominoes"*** (suggested by [Bubbler](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/71652)) and will span from the **21st of March to the 3rd of April**. During this period, we will compile the list of relevant questions and post it as an answer to this question.

**In the meantime, please go and [propose and vote on future challenges!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7032)**

Everyone have fun, and happy puzzling!

<sub>*Link to [other](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20title%3a%22Fortnightly%20Topic%20Challenge%20%23) Fortnightly Topic Challenges.*</sub>

***NOTE***
The suggestion is copied to this post for posterity.

> ### Polyominoes
>
> [polyomino](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polyomino) often goes with other tags, such as
>
> - [tiling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tiling), as in [Tiling with T-tetrominos in gravity](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/49665/71652)
> - [combinatorics](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combinatorics) (which is also often combined with [tiling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tiling)), as in [L-tromino pair!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/101154/71652)
> - [grid-deduction](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid-deduction) as a genre mashup, as in [Tetronogram](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/86652/71652) or [Tetromino minesweeper](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/102676/71652)
> - sometimes [board-games](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/board-games), as in [What is the minimum-sized Blokus board which can contain all pieces?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/94835/71652)
>
> but may also be a successful puzzle by itself, as in [Polyominoes to construct alphabet](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/95090/71652).
>
> [Polyomino](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polyomino.html) is a long-time subject of recreational mathematics, and its properties can be used for grid deductions in many creative ways. So the challenge is to create a puzzle related to polyominoes in a creative way. Of course it does not need to be polyominoes made of squares; it can be [polyiamonds](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polyiamond.html) (made of triangles) or [polyhexes](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polyhex.html) (made of hexagons) too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**List of all questions published as part of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge #52:**

- [A constrained, but concerning, celestial confrontation](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/109126) by [JeremyDover](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/69217)
- [Polly O'Mino's Hexcellent Adventure](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/109143) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644)
- *add further entries in the form
  `https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/<question-ID> by [username](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)`*

---

The **highest-voted** *and* the **most viewed** puzzles will be recorded here at the end of the fortnight.