# Monthly Topic Challenge #8: Cellular Automata

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This is the eighth installment of the Monthly Topic Challenges with topics suggested and voted on [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7265). This month's topic is ***"Cellular Automata"*** (suggested by [melfnt](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/63414)) and will span from the **1st of March to the 31st of March**. During this period, we will compile the list of relevant questions and post it as an answer to this question.

**In the meantime, please go and [propose and vote on future challenges!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7265)**

Everyone have fun, and happy puzzling!

<sub>*Link to [other](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20title%3a%22Monthly%20Topic%20Challenge%20%23) Monthly Topic Challenges.*</sub>

***NOTE***
The suggestion is copied to this post for posterity.

> ### Cellular Automata
>
> Here's a regular tag that doesn't seem to get much love: [cellular-automata](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cellular-automata)
>
> This can involve puzzles about a well-known cellular automaton, like for example [Conway's Game of Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life), or a cellular automaton you've created on your own!
>
> Get creative! Maybe we need to reverse-engineer something, try to produce a certain output with given starting conditions, or something entirely different! Crossovers are of course allowed and encouraged.
>
> Great examples of puzzles on this site are [Game of Life: Kill the Sun](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/31247/game-of-life-kill-the-sun), [Can you recreate this fractal I randomly made?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/43311/can-you-recreate-this-fractal-i-randomly-made) and [Checkerboard Infection](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/18074/checkerboard-infection)
>
> ---
>
> <sup>copied from [Fortnightly Topic Challenges Threrun: Topic Suggestions](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7032/fortnightly-topic-challenges-threrun-topic-suggestions) originally posted by [Lukas Rotter](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/37714/lukas-rotter)</sup>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**List of all questions published as part of the Monthly Topic Challenge #8:**

| Puzzle | Creator |
| --- | --- |
| [Personal Names Turn Around](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/119949/personal-names-turn-around) | [Scratch---Cat](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/54367/scratch-cat) |
| [Two Blinkers, A Pair of Boats](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/120153/two-blinkers-a-pair-of-boats) | [Amoz](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/70710/amoz) |
| [HalfLife: A Cellular Automaton](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/120173/halflife-a-cellular-automaton) | [Jeremy Dover](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/69217/jeremy-dover) |
| [A Message Of Encouragement](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/120234/a-message-of-encouragement) | [Scratch---Cat](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/54367/scratch-cat) |

---

The **highest-voted** three of these are:

- [Two Blinkers, A Pair of Boats, etc](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/120153) by [Amoz](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/70710), with a score of **12** at the end of the month.
- [HalfLife: A Cellular Automaton](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/120173) by [Jeremy Dover](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/69217), with a score of **10** at the end of the month.
- [Personal Names Turn Around](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/119949) by [Scratch---Cat](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/54367), with a score of **3** at the end of the month.

The **most viewed** three of these are:

- [Two Blinkers, A Pair of Boats, etc](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/120153) by [Amoz](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/70710), with **449** views at the end of the month.
- [A Message Of Encouragement](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/120234) by [Scratch---Cat](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/54367), with **273** views at the end of the month.
- [HalfLife: A Cellular Automaton](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/120173) by [Jeremy Dover](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/69217), with **235** views at the end of the month.