# Monthly Topic Challenge #9: Game/Quiz Shows

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This is the ninth installment of the Monthly Topic Challenges with topics suggested and voted on [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7265). This month's topic is ***"Game/Quiz Shows"*** (suggested by [HTM](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/57742)) and will span from the **1st of April to the 30th of April**. During this period, we will compile the list of relevant questions and post it as an answer to this question.

**In the meantime, please go and [propose and vote on future challenges!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7265)**

Everyone have fun, and happy puzzling!

<sub>*Link to [other](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20title%3a%22Monthly%20Topic%20Challenge%20%23) Monthly Topic Challenges.*</sub>

***NOTE***
The suggestion is copied to this post for posterity.

> ### Game/Quiz Shows
>
> > *This... is... Puzzling! Let's meet this month's topic challengers...*
>
> Create a puzzle themed around a real-life game or quiz show. The puzzle **must involve the basic format of the overall show in some way**, e.g. a *Jeopardy!*-themed puzzle might include answering trivia questions chosen from a board, while an *Only Connect*-themed puzzle might include [sequence](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence) questions *and* a [connect-wall](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/connect-wall).
>
> Some examples on this site, including the game/quiz shows they reference:
>
> - [Let's spin the wheel!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/24661/57742) - *Wheel of Fortune*
> - The [Slumdog millionaire](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/11226/57742) series - *Who Wants to Be a Millionaire?*
> - [Can I have a 'P' please, Bob?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/107757/57742) - [*Blockbusters*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blockbusters_(American_game_show)) (this is what inspired me to come up with this proposal)
>
> And Wikipedia has ["Lists of game shows"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_game_shows) from a variety of countries, linked here for informational and inspirational purposes.
>
> **Notes:**
>
> - Puzzles that are dressed up as or reference game/quiz shows but do not directly involve the format of a real-life show *are not eligible* for this challenge, e.g. the [connect-wall](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/connect-wall)
> - Puzzles asking about *optimal strategies* for playing game/quiz shows *are eligible*, as long as what the "best" strategy is can be objectively quantified, e.g. [Monopoly Game Show: Is there a winning strategy?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/19848/57742)
>
> ---
>
> <sup>Copied from my submission for the [Fortnightly Topic Challenges Threrun](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7181/57742) (over a year and a half ago... time flies huh?)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**List of all questions published as part of the Monthly Topic Challenge #9:**

| Puzzle | Creator |
| --- | --- |
| [Patrick Terne Wants to Be a Millionaire](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/120466/patrick-terne-wants-to-be-a-millionaire) | [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644/stiv) |
| [Only Connect - all at once!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/120473/only-connect-all-at-once) | [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644/stiv) |
| [Deal or No Deal, Puzzling Edition](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/120477/deal-or-no-deal-puzzling-edition) | [Amoz](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/70710/amoz) |
| ['Pointless' US states](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/120484/pointless-us-states) | [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644/stiv) |

---

The **highest-voted** three of these are:

- [Only Connect - all at once!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/120473) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644), with a score of **19** at the end of the month.
- [Deal or No Deal, Puzzling Edition](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/120477) by [Amoz](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/70710), with a score of **19** at the end of the month.
- ['Pointless' US states](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/120484) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644), with a score of **16** at the end of the month.

The **most viewed** three of these are:

- [Only Connect - all at once!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/120473) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644), with **1382** views at the end of the month.
- [Deal or No Deal, Puzzling Edition](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/120477) by [Amoz](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/70710), with **1246** views at the end of the month.
- [Patrick Terne Wants to Be a Millionaire](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/120466) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644), with **987** views at the end of the month.