# Fortnightly Topic Challenge #2: Outer Space

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

*Link to [other](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3Aquestion%20Fortnightly%20Topic%20Challenge%20%23) Fortnightly Topics.*

---

This is the second installment of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge described [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2841/should-we-have-weekly-fortnightly-topic-challenges) with topics suggested and voted for [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/what-should-be-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges). This fortnight's topic is [outer-space](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/outer-space) and will span from Sep. 23 - Oct. 7. During this period, we will compile the list of questions featuring this topic and post it as an answer to this question.

In the meantime, please go [propose and vote on future challenges!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/what-should-be-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges)

Everyone have fun and happy puzzling!!

Comment: @Emrakul: Time to close this challenge...

Comment: @CodeNewbie Will handle tomorrow unless NeedAName or someone else gets to it first; busy night

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**List of puzzles in this category:**

1. [Message to Survivors](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/22551/message-to-survivors)
   by [NeedAName](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/13970/needaname)
2. [A rare sight indeed](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/22563/a-rare-sight-indeed) by [Gordon K](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/14135/gordon-k)
3. [An outer-space riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/22564/an-outer-space-riddle) by [Timmy](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/16273/timmy)
4. [Second star to the right and straight on t'il morning](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/22598/second-star-to-the-right-and-straight-on-til-morning) by [Spacemonkey](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/11251/spacemonkey)
5. [Mr. Hilbert and the Message from Outer Space](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/22612/mr-hilbert-and-the-message-from-outer-space) by [Hackiisan](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/15960/hackiisan)
6. [Cryptic Quote #1: To Infinity and Beyond!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/22626/cryptic-quote-1-to-infinity-and-beyond) by [Bailey M](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/11475/bailey-m)
7. [I am One Out of Fourteen](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/22711/i-am-one-out-of-fourteen) by [APrough](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/14233/aprough)
8. [The Case of the Strange Astronomy Test](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/22715/the-case-of-the-strange-astronomy-test) by [Anachor](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/15544/anachor)
9. [Twinkle Twinkle Bob Junior the Umpth](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/22756/twinkle-twinkle-bob-junior-the-umpth) by [Spacemonkey](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/11251/spacemonkey)
10. [I'm Going to the Moon!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/22776/im-going-to-the-moon) by [Takeshi](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/16566/takeshi)
11. [There's no chemistry in this class](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/22782/theres-no-chemistry-in-this-class) by [Gordon K](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/14135/gordon-k)

<sub>You can also find the list [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=[outer-space]%20created%3a2015-9-22..2015-10-07%20is%3aquestion).</sub>

Comment: Someone needs to come up with an answer for the last one. Its eating me up.