# Fortnightly Topic Challenge #3: Video Games

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

*Link to [other](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3Aquestion%20Fortnightly%20Topic%20Challenge%20%23) Fortnightly Topics.*

---

This is the third installment of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge described [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2841/should-we-have-weekly-fortnightly-topic-challenges) with topics suggested and voted for [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/what-should-be-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges). This fortnight's topic is [video-games](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video-games) and will span from Oct. 8 - Oct. 21. During this period, we will compile the list of questions featuring this topic and post it as an answer to this question.

In the meantime, please go [propose and vote on future challenges!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/what-should-be-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges)

Everyone have fun and happy puzzling!!

Comment: hmm, this seems a lot less popular than i thought it'd be

Comment: Note: There is a place at http://gaming.stackexchange.com for puzzle-based-computer-games.

Answer (score 4):

Questions so far are:

1. [Entertainment Discombobulation](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23008/entertainement-discombobulation/23014#23014) by [Spacemonkey](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/11251/spacemonkey)
2. [Dungeon Crawler - Level 1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23025/dungeon-crawler-level-1) by [NeedAName](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/13970/needaname)
3. [Dungeon Crawler - Level 2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23056/dungeon-crawler-level-2) by [NeedAName](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/13970/needaname)
4. [Dungeon Crawler - Level 2.5](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23155/dungeon-crawler-level-2-5) by [NeedAName](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/13970/needaname)
5. [Dungeon Crawler - Level 3](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23157/dungeon-crawler-level-3) by [NeedAName](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/13970/needaname)
6. [Dungeon Crawler - Final Level](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23384/dungeon-crawler-final-level) by [NeedAName](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/13970/needaname)
7. [The Famous Last Words Square](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23059/the-famous-last-words-square) by [Sleafar](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/15632/sleafar)
8. [Characters make the game](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23071/characters-make-the-game) by [Sleafar](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/15632/sleafar)
9. [Eat It! Through Multi Paths](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23193/eat-it-through-multi-paths) by [Mythi](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/15921/mythi)
10. [My Life…Sucks](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23199/my-life-sucks) by [raisinghellyer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/11452/raisinghellyer)
11. [Video Games Cryptic Crossword](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23290/video-games-cryptic-crossword) by [Gordon K](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/14135/gordon-k)
12. [A Multi-leveled Gaming Concept](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23326/a-multi-leveled-gaming-concept) by [Fillet](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/7316/fillet)
13. [Enemies are Everywhere I Look!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23351/enemies-are-everywhere-i-look) by [raisinghellyer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/11452/raisinghellyer)
14. [The Letter of the Law](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23387/the-letter-of-the-law) by [GentlePurpleRain](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/4421/gentlepurplerain)

<sub>You can also find the list [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5Bvideo-games%5D%20created%3a2015-10-08..2015-10-21%20is%3aquestion)</sub>

Comment: 2 missing i think, no time to edit - feel free anyone