# Monthly Topic Challenge #2: IQ Puzzle Parody

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This is the second installment of the Monthly Topic Challenges with topics suggested and voted on [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7265). This month's topic is ***"IQ Puzzle Parody"*** (suggested by [Stiv](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/60644)) and will span from the **1st of August to the 31st of August**. During this period, we will compile the list of relevant questions and post it as an answer to this question.

**In the meantime, please go and [propose and vote on future challenges!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7265)**

Everyone have fun, and happy puzzling!

<sub>*Link to [other](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20title%3a%22Monthly%20Topic%20Challenge%20%23) Monthly Topic Challenges.*</sub>

***NOTE***
The suggestion is copied to this post for posterity.

> ### IQ Puzzle Parody
>
> With frustrating regularity, PSE goes through periods of being overrun by requests for help with IQ questions found online or in interviews - most commonly of the type "Here's a bunch of boxes containing some kind of pattern - what image should go in the last box?" Often these questions are low-effort contributions to the site and highlight the very worst of 'guess what I'm thinking' type corporate exercises...
>
> *This is ripe for parody!*
>
> I propose a challenge where the user should strive to create a puzzle that resembles one of these IQ puzzles but actually disguises *another puzzle or puzzle mechanism altogether*. The multiple-box design could, for example, lend itself nicely to [grid-deduction](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid-deduction) puzzles, [cipher](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cipher)s or puzzles with another clever [visual](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visual) component.
>
> There's a world of possibilities here, and the opportunity for some fun at the expense of a widely disliked puzzle type...!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**List of all questions published as part of the Monthly Topic Challenge #2:**

| Puzzle | Creator |
| --- | --- |
| [A Progressive Flag Matrix](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/117358/a-progressive-flag-matrix) | [RogerA](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/77471/rogera) |
| [Did I copy that wrong?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/117361/did-i-copy-that-wrong) | [quarague](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/71039/quarague) |
| [Which of these is the answer?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/117393/which-of-these-is-the-answer) | [juicifer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/77182/juicifer) |
| [I need help with this IQ test puzzle I found online](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/117390/i-need-help-with-this-iq-test-puzzle-i-found-online) | [SeptaCube](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/71616/septacube) |
| [I need a help with this HQ test puzzle I found online](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/117397/i-need-a-help-with-this-hq-test-puzzle-i-found-online) | [melfnt](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/63414/melfnt) |
| [Help! Help! My IQ!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/117413/help-help-my-iq) | [Jafe](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/41973/jafe) |
| [Help me with this triangles-and-points iq puzzle, please!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/117415/help-me-with-this-triangles-and-points-iq-puzzle-please) | [new QOpenGLWidget](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/56715/new-qopenglwidget) |
| [“IQ” puzzles seem to be flooding this site](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/117419/iq-puzzles-seem-to-be-flooding-this-site) | [Amoz](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/70710/amoz) |
| [My IQ will be so high if someone can solve this for me](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/117497/my-iq-will-be-so-high-if-someone-can-solve-this-for-me) | [Jafe](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/41973/jafe) |
| [Another pseudo-IQ question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/117507/another-pseudo-iq-question) | [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644/stiv) |
| [An IQ test for the brave](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/117519/an-iq-test-for-the-brave) | [Auribouros](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/78764/auribouros) |
| [Radical IQ challenge](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/117525/radical-iq-challenge) | [PuzzlingFerret](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/9316/puzzlingferret) |
| [How do I solve these Math IQ problems?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/117548/how-do-i-solve-these-math-iq-problems) | [ACB](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/78877/acb) |
| [This IQ test appears to be corrupted](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/117619/this-iq-test-appears-to-be-corrupted) | [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644/stiv) |
| [The Oracle's IQ Test](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/117697/the-oracles-iq-test) | [cap](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/57156/cap) |
| [Sergeant Sequence faces his toughest (IQ) test yet](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/117702/sergeant-sequence-faces-his-toughest-iq-test-yet) | [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644/stiv) |
| [IQ Puzzle with a Twist](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/117703/iq-puzzle-with-a-twist) | [Angelica](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/22637/angelica) |

---

The **highest-voted** three of these are:

- [“IQ” puzzles seem to be flooding this site](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/117419) by [Amoz](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/70710), with a score of **37** at the end of the month.
- [My IQ will be so high if someone can solve this for me](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/117497) by [Jafe](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/41973), with a score of **25** at the end of the month.
- [The Oracle's IQ Test](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/117697) by [cap](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/57156), with a score of **24** at the end of the month.

The **most viewed** three of these are:

- [My IQ will be so high if someone can solve this for me](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/117497) by [Jafe](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/41973), with **4821** views at the end of the month.
- [“IQ” puzzles seem to be flooding this site](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/117419) by [Amoz](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/70710), with **4812** views at the end of the month.
- [Radical IQ challenge](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/117525) by [PuzzlingFerret](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/9316), with **3607** views at the end of the month.