# Monthly Topic Challenge #3: Pencil and Paper Games

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This is the third installment of the Monthly Topic Challenges with topics suggested and voted on [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7265). This month's topic is ***"[pencil-and-paper-games](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pencil-and-paper-games)"*** (suggested by [bobble](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/69582)) and will span from the **1st of September to the 30th of September**. During this period, we will compile the list of relevant questions and post it as an answer to this question.

**In the meantime, please go and [propose and vote on future challenges!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7265)**

Everyone have fun, and happy puzzling!

<sub>*Link to [other](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20title%3a%22Monthly%20Topic%20Challenge%20%23) Monthly Topic Challenges.*</sub>

***NOTE***
The suggestion is copied to this post for posterity.

> ### [pencil-and-paper-games](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pencil-and-paper-games)
>
> Throwing a purely tag-based one in...
>
> Games meant to be played with a pencil and paper tend to be simple little time wasters. But that doesn't mean they can't be incorporated into puzzles in interesting ways! Their very simplicity means puzzles with them can still be easily understandable/accessible even if a little more complex.
>
> This challenge is to create a puzzle deserving of the tag, or a related one like [tic-tac-toe](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tic-tac-toe), even if using it would be a "spoiler" - so an [enigmatic-puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/enigmatic-puzzle) which is edited into the list of challenge puzzles after a solve is perfectly fine. Puzzles would be about the pencil/paper games (strategy etc.), simply incorporate ideas/rules from them in some way (e.g. a Sudoku which has a Dots and Boxes variety rule), or involve such a game in some other significant part of the solve process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**List of all questions published as part of the Monthly Topic Challenge #3:**

| Puzzle | Creator |
| --- | --- |
| [Dots and boxes, 2 against 1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/117840/dots-and-boxes-2-against-1) | [Retudin](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/71170/retudin) |
| [What is my favorite brand of pen?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/117864/what-is-my-favorite-brand-of-pen) | [Amoz](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/70710/amoz) |
| [Noughts and Crosses and... there's more?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/117866/noughts-and-crosses-and-theres-more) | [Beastly Gerbil](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/18250/beastly-gerbil) |
| [Reconstruct the lost labyrinth of Knossos](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/117873/reconstruct-the-lost-labyrinth-of-knossos) | [Florian F](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/2136/florian-f) |
| [Pigpen Tic-Tac-Toe](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/117980/pigpen-tic-tac-toe) | [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644/stiv) |
| [They are all linked!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/118043/they-are-all-linked) | [ACB](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/78877/acb) |
| [We're just hanging out, man](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/118072/were-just-hanging-out-man) | [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644/stiv) |
| [A game of some consequence](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/118156/a-game-of-some-consequence) | [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644/stiv) |

---

---

The **highest-voted** three of these are:

- [Reconstruct the lost labyrinth of Knossos](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/117873) by [Florian F](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/2136), with a score of **16** at the end of the month.
- [We're just hanging out, man](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/118072) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644), with a score of **15** at the end of the month.
- [What is my favorite brand of pen?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/117864) by [Amoz](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/70710), with a score of **10** at the end of the month.

The **most viewed** three of these are:

- [We're just hanging out, man](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/118072) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644), with **2209** views at the end of the month.
- [Pigpen Tic-Tac-Toe](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/117980) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644), with **889** views at the end of the month.
- [Reconstruct the lost labyrinth of Knossos](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/117873) by [Florian F](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/2136), with **828** views at the end of the month.

Comment: I really like the "We're just hanging out, man". It's very clever, and also maybe because if I see another tic-tac-toe board I might go insane. haha