# Monthly Topic Challenge #5: On-and-onograms

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This is the fifth installment of the Monthly Topic Challenges with topics suggested and voted on [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7265). This month's topic is ***"On-and-onograms"*** (suggested by [Stiv](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/60644)) and will span from the **1st of November to the 30th of November**. During this period, we will compile the list of relevant questions and post it as an answer to this question.

**In the meantime, please go and [propose and vote on future challenges!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7265)**

Everyone have fun, and happy puzzling!

<sub>*Link to [other](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20title%3a%22Monthly%20Topic%20Challenge%20%23) Monthly Topic Challenges.*</sub>

***NOTE***
The suggestion is copied to this post for posterity.

> ### On-and-onograms
>
> Create a puzzle where the first step is a [nonogram](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nonogram) whose solution reveals further steps that must be taken. Crucially, *the full puzzle is entirely self-contained within the nonogram and flavour text*. (i.e. Not just using a nonogram as the first step in a long string of grid-deduction puzzles which require additional grids to be displayed in the post.)
>
> Good examples from the past include [these](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/84058/60644) [two](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/84266/60644) puzzles by @jafe, one of which conceals a [rebus](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rebus) and the other a set of [sequence](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence) puzzles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**List of all questions published as part of the Monthly Topic Challenge #5:**

| Puzzle | Creator |
| --- | --- |
| [Kind of like a clock, kind of like a path…](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/118590/kind-of-like-a-clock-kind-of-like-a-path) | [Amoz](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/70710/amoz) |
| [Sergeant Sequence brings in the analysts](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/118612/sergeant-sequence-brings-in-the-analysts) | [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644/stiv) |
| [A Valentine's nonoGram](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/118616/a-valentines-nonogram) | [WoomyRogue](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/75335/woomyrogue) |
| [A Weapon or a Toy?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/118660/a-weapon-or-a-toy) | [ACB](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/78877/acb) |
| [This new puzzle type needs a name {7}](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/118681/this-new-puzzle-type-needs-a-name-7) | [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644/stiv) |

---

The **highest-voted** three of these are:

- [A Weapon or a Toy?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/118660) by [ACB](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/81979), with a score of **62** at the end of the month.
- [This new puzzle type needs a name {7}](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/118681) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644), with a score of **25** at the end of the month.
- [Sergeant Sequence brings in the analysts](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/118612) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644), with a score of **15** at the end of the month.

The **most viewed** three of these are:

- [A Weapon or a Toy?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/118660) by [ACB](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/81979), with **4744** views at the end of the month.
- [This new puzzle type needs a name {7}](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/118681) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644), with **2087** views at the end of the month.
- [A Valentine's nonoGram](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/118616) by [WoomyRogue](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/75335), with **1124** views at the end of the month.