# Monthly Topic Challenge #7: Board games

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This is the seventh installment of the Monthly Topic Challenges with topics suggested and voted on [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7265). This month's topic is ***"Board games"*** (suggested by [PuzzlingFerret](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/9316)) and will span from the **1st of February to the 28th of February**. During this period, we will compile the list of relevant questions and post it as an answer to this question.

**In the meantime, please go and [propose and vote on future challenges!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7265)**

Everyone have fun, and happy puzzling!

<sub>*Link to [other](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20title%3a%22Monthly%20Topic%20Challenge%20%23) Monthly Topic Challenges.*</sub>

***NOTE***
The suggestion is copied to this post for posterity.

> ### Board games
>
> Create a puzzle about a real world **board game**. Any board game will do, but I suspect a classic game might do better.
>
> #### What's a board game?
>
> Almost anything, besides card games, on the sister stack [Board & Card Games](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com).
>
> Some ideas:
>
> - Monopoly themed [crosswords](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crosswords)
> - SlitherLinks and other [grid-deduction](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid-deduction) puzzles in the shape of a board game like Ludo or Solitaire.
> - "How did we get into this state?" Type puzzles that show a game part way through in an unusual state.
>
> #### Does it have to be *just* boardgame related?
>
> No! The cluedo board game has a film, feel free to involve that! Puzzles about monopoly could also reference the economics term!
>
> #### The Chess Piece in the room
>
> There's already a bunch of [chess](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chess) puzzles, do we want more? Sure, why not? But they might need to do more to standout against the puzzles already on the site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**List of all questions published as part of the Monthly Topic Challenge #7:**

| Puzzle | Creator |
| --- | --- |
| [Colorblind Mastermind](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/119593/colorblind-mastermind) | [Scratch---Cat](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/54367/scratch-cat) |
| [Sixty-three knights on a chessboard](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/119608/sixty-three-knights-on-a-chessboard) | [Scratch---Cat](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/54367/scratch-cat) |
| [From white to black](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/119614/from-white-to-black) | [Scratch---Cat](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/54367/scratch-cat) |
| [The body in the cellar](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/119701/the-body-in-the-cellar) | [Amoz](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/70710/amoz) |
| [Farthest From Backgammon](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/119766/farthest-from-backgammon) | [Scratch---Cat](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/54367/scratch-cat) |
| [Themed Boggle Grids Continued](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/119796/themed-boggle-grids-continued) | [Scratch---Cat](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/54367/scratch-cat) |
| [Boggle Everywhere](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/119797/boggle-everywhere) | [Scratch---Cat](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/54367/scratch-cat) |
| [Trochaic hexameter](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/119846/trochaic-hexameter) | [Scratch---Cat](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/54367/scratch-cat) |
| [Circuissonne Diagrams](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/119863/circuissonne-diagrams) | [Scratch---Cat](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/54367/scratch-cat) |
| ["Guess Where?" - a GCHQ word association puzzle (board game edition)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/119926/) | [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644/stiv) |
| [Riley Riddle in the game](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/119932/riley-riddle-in-the-game) | [Scratch---Cat](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/54367/scratch-cat) |

---

The **highest-voted** three of these are:

- [The body in the cellar](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/119701) by [Amoz](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/70710), with a score of **28** at the end of the month.
- [Riley Riddle in the game](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/119932) by [Scratch---Cat](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/54367), with a score of **10** at the end of the month.
- [Colorblind Mastermind](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/119593) by [Scratch---Cat](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/54367), with a score of **7** at the end of the month.

The **most viewed** three of these are:

- [The body in the cellar](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/119701) by [Amoz](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/70710), with **1921** views at the end of the month.
- [Sixty-three knights on a chessboard](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/119608) by [Scratch---Cat](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/54367), with **1262** views at the end of the month.
- [Colorblind Mastermind](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/119593) by [Scratch---Cat](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/54367), with **832** views at the end of the month.