# Monthly Topic Challenge #11: Now in 3D

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This is the eleventh installment of the Monthly Topic Challenges with topics suggested and voted on [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7265). This month's topic is ***"Now in 3D"*** (suggested by [Jafe](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/41973)) and will span from the **1st of June to the 30th of June**. During this period, we will compile the list of relevant questions and post it as an answer to this question.

**In the meantime, please go and [propose and vote on future challenges!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7265)**

Everyone have fun, and happy puzzling!

<sub>*Link to [other](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20title%3a%22Monthly%20Topic%20Challenge%20%23) Monthly Topic Challenges.*</sub>

***NOTE***
The suggestion is copied to this post for posterity.

> ### Now in 3D
>
> The [three-dimensional](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/three-dimensional) tag can bring a nice twist to a variety of puzzle types. We've seen [paper folding](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/100949/two-chunky-pixelated-xs-locked-in-mortal-combat), [grid deduction](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/87558/isometric-heyacrazy-now-in-3d), [crosswords](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/115242/variety-gridlocks), [mazes](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/104507/chain-puzzle-tabletop-games-7-maze) and even [pencil-and-paper game](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/86072/reverse-dots-and-cubes-snowflake-edition) puzzles use the extra dimension to great effect. While presenting 3D things in a 2D environment brings some challenges to both setters and solvers, the added dimension offers a nice opportunity to produce some real mind benders when done right. Creativity is encouraged – the only requirement here is that the puzzle somehow make use of three-dimensional space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**List of all questions published as part of the Monthly Topic Challenge #11:**

| Puzzle | Creator |
| --- | --- |
| [The Nine Gardens Of Eden](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/121054/the-nine-gardens-of-eden) | [Scratch---Cat](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/54367/scratch-cat) |
| [Odd solutions are in 3d](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/121058/odd-solutions-are-in-3d) | [quarague](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/71039/quarague) |
| [Brit’s Alphabet Block Cube](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/121238/brit-s-alphabet-block-cube) | [Amoz](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/70710/amoz) |
| [Introducing the 3D Connecting Wall!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/121327/introducing-the-3d-connecting-wall) | [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644/stiv) |
| [Re-producing the 3D Connecting Wall!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/121359/re-producing-the-3d-connecting-wall) | [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644/stiv) |
| [Can you pack these pentacubes to form a rectangular block with at least one odd side length other the side whose length must be a multiple of 5](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/121372/can-you-pack-these-pentacubes-to-form-a-rectangular-block-with-at-least-one-odd) | [Will Octagon Gibson](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/80061/will-octagon-gibson) |

---

The **highest-voted** three of these are:

- [Introducing the 3D Connecting Wall!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/121327) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644), with a score of **16** at the end of the month.
- [Brit’s Alphabet Block Cube](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/121238) by [Amoz](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/70710), with a score of **14** at the end of the month.
- [Re-producing the 3D Connecting Wall!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/121359) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644), with a score of **12** at the end of the month.

The **most viewed** three of these are:

- [Introducing the 3D Connecting Wall!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/121327) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644), with **1539** views at the end of the month.
- [Odd solutions are in 3d](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/121058) by [quarague](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/71039), with **813** views at the end of the month.
- [Re-producing the 3D Connecting Wall!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/121359) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644), with **681** views at the end of the month.