# Monthly Topic Challenge #12: mobile-friendly puzzles

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This is the twelfth installment of the Monthly Topic Challenges with topics suggested and voted on [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7265). This month's topic is ***"mobile-friendly puzzles"*** (suggested by [Amoz](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/70710)) and will span from the **1st of July to the 31st of July**. During this period, we will compile the list of relevant questions and post it as an answer to this question.

**In the meantime, please go and [propose and vote on future challenges!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7265)**

Everyone have fun, and happy puzzling!

<sub>*Link to [other](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20title%3a%22Monthly%20Topic%20Challenge%20%23) Monthly Topic Challenges.*</sub>

***NOTE***
The suggestion is copied to this post for posterity.

> **mobile-friendly puzzles**
>
> Why is this post so badly formatted you may ask?
> Well it's because I am dictating into a mobile phone.
>
> a lot of us are busy and on the go these days and don't have time to sit at the computer and solve puzzles but we'd still love to have some fun.
> I propose for the monthly topic challenge *mobile friendly puzzles*.  These are puzzles which can easily be solved on your mobile phone using common knowledge or perhaps looking up a few things, but not poring over complicated charts or graphs, using Excel, filling out drawings, or requiring extensive markup or time writing out a beautifully formatted entry.
> Creating a good mobile-friendly puzzle is a true challenge for a Puzzle Master for they must create a puzzle that is simple enough to be viewed and solved on a mobile device and yet elegant, interesting, and unique. It should be answerable in a few lines of text or perhaps by uploading a simple screenshot with minimal markup.
> There are plenty of examples on this site; here's one at random:
> [It's a... Ohh... puzzle (BpFp)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/116182/its-a-ohh-puzzle-bpfp)
>
> Clarification:
> In the spirit of this being a *Challenge*, entries should be *innovative and new* in some way, to the op's knowledge. For example:
> -Something that looks like an affix-riddle or What is a Word, but is actually something else entirely, or takes a new or unexpected twist.
> -A puzzle with a visual component leveraging a never seen before mechanism.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**List of all questions published as part of the Monthly Topic Challenge #12:**

| Puzzle | Creator |
| --- | --- |
| [Cleaning out the garage](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/121392/cleaning-out-the-garage) | [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644/stiv) |
| [This won't work with US states](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/121419/this-wont-work-with-us-states) | [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644/stiv) |
| [More Like This 2:?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/121466/more-like-this-2) | [Scratch---Cat](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/54367/scratch-cat) |
| [How many do we have?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/121595/how-many-do-we-have) | [RogerA](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/77471/rogera) |
| [Calculate nothing](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/121600/calculate-nothing) | [Lezzup](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/84683/lezzup) |
| [Mapping single-words to lists](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/121611/mapping-single-words-to-lists) | [chandanr777](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/81104/chandanr777) |
| [A connecting wall for series 1?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/121737/a-connecting-wall-for-series-1) | [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644/stiv) |
| [A confusing sign](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/121734/a-confusing-sign) | [Amoz](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/70710/amoz) |
| [Arithmetic operation](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/121694/arithmetic-operation) | [JRN](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5095/jrn) |

---

The **highest-voted** three of these are:

- [Cleaning out the garage](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/121392) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644), with a score of **27** at the end of the month.
- [A connecting wall for series 1?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/121737) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644), with a score of **24** at the end of the month.
- [A confusing sign](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/121734) by [Amoz](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/70710), with a score of **22** at the end of the month.

The **most viewed** three of these are:

- [A confusing sign](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/121734) by [Amoz](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/70710), with **2012** views at the end of the month.
- [This won't work with US states](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/121419) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644), with **1736** views at the end of the month.
- [Cleaning out the garage](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/121392) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644), with **1664** views at the end of the month.