# Monthly Topic Challenge #13: Variety Slitherlinks

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This is the thirteenth installment of the Monthly Topic Challenges with topics suggested and voted on [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7265). This month's topic is ***"Variety Slitherlinks"*** (suggested by [sarsaparilla](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/60396)) and will span from the **1st of August to the 31st of August**. During this period, we will compile the list of relevant questions and post it as an answer to this question.

**In the meantime, please go and [propose and vote on future challenges!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7265)**

Everyone have fun, and happy puzzling!

<sub>*Link to [other](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20title%3a%22Monthly%20Topic%20Challenge%20%23) Monthly Topic Challenges.*</sub>

***NOTE***
The suggestion is copied to this post for posterity.

> ### Variety Slitherlinks
>
> The challenge is to create a puzzle that shows an original perspective on the basic slitherlink puzzle.
>
> It could have:
>
> - slightly altered rules (why not 2 loops instead of 1?)
> - a non-standard grid (hexagonal? non-2D?)
> - show clues in a way one wouldn't expect
> - combine multiple slitherlinks in one grid
> - combine slitherlink rules with other grid-deduction puzzle types
> - hide some encrypted information that the puzzler should decode
> - any other enigmatic twist that you can think of
>
> I've created a [Slitherlink with a message](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/107123/slitherlink-with-a-message) before, and I like the originality of [Rhombicosidodecahedron Slitherlink](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/86459/rhombicosidodecahedron-slitherlink) and [9x9 Sudoku Slitherlink Hybrid](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/109371/9x9-sudoku-slitherlink-hybrid).

Comment: Just a general note: this puzzling website contains a wide variety of slitherlink puzzles with non-square grids: https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/puzzles/js/loopy.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**List of all questions published as part of the Monthly Topic Challenge #13:**

| Puzzle | Creator |
| --- | --- |
| [The Metaslitherlink](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/121823/the-metaslitherlink) | [sarsaparilla](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60396/sarsaparilla) |
| [Slitherlink? I hardly know her!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/121837/slitherlink-i-hardly-know-her) | [Jafe](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/41973/jafe) |
| [An oddly coloured slitherlink](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/121841/an-oddly-coloured-slitherlink) | [fljx](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/76997/fljx) |
| [SlitherLITS: Don't colour outside the lines](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/121854/slitherlits-dont-colour-outside-the-lines) | [fljx](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/76997/fljx) |
| [An X x X Slitherlink related to X](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/121948/an-x-x-x-slitherlink-related-to-x) | [Amoz](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/70710/amoz) |
| [Slither-Numberlink: A monstrosity nature never intended](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/121956/slither-numberlink-a-monstrosity-nature-never-intended) | [Jafe](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/41973/jafe) |
| [Walking a twisted path on a donut - a Möbius Slitherlink](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/121974/walking-a-twisted-path-on-a-donut-a-m%c3%b6bius-slitherlink) | [fljx](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/76997/fljx) |
| [Double trouble - When slitherloops collide](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/122001/double-trouble-when-slitherloops-collide) | [fljx](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/76997/fljx) |
| [A Watery Slitherlink](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/122103/a-watery-slitherlink) | [new Q Open Wid](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/56715/new-q-open-wid) |
| [Slither-Yajilink: A match made in Hades](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/122157/slither-yajilink-a-match-made-in-hades) | [Jafe](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/41973/jafe) |

---

The **highest-voted** three of these are:

- [The Metaslitherlink](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/121823) by [sarsaparilla](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60396), with a score of **21** at the end of the month.
- [An oddly coloured slitherlink](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/121841) by [fljx](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/76997), with a score of **17** at the end of the month.
- [SlitherLITS: Don't colour outside the lines](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/121854) by [fljx](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/76997), with a score of **16** at the end of the month.

The **most viewed** three of these are:

- [Slitherlink? I hardly know her!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/121837) by [Jafe](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/41973), with **1059** views at the end of the month.
- [The Metaslitherlink](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/121823) by [sarsaparilla](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60396), with **938** views at the end of the month.
- [An oddly coloured slitherlink](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/121841) by [fljx](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/76997), with **927** views at the end of the month.