# Monthly Topic Challenge #14: Think inside the (very small) box!

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This is the fourteenth installment of the Monthly Topic Challenges with topics suggested and voted on [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7265). This month's topic is ***"Think inside the (very small) box!"*** (suggested by [Stiv](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/60644)) and will span from the **1st of September to the 30th of September 2023**. During this period, we will compile the list of relevant questions and post it as an answer to this question.

**In the meantime, please go and [propose and vote on future challenges!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7265)**

Everyone have fun, and happy puzzling!

<sub>*Link to [other](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20title%3a%22Monthly%20Topic%20Challenge%20%23) Monthly Topic Challenges.*</sub>

***NOTE***
The suggestion is copied to this post for posterity.

> ### Think inside the (very small) box!
>
> This challenge is a simple one - create a puzzle based on a small square grid. Grids must be 2x2, 3x3, 4x4, or 5x5 in size - no bigger!
>
> The grid itself does not have to be small in physical size - for example, you may wish to fill each square with an image or a sentence; this is fine. The challenge is to restrict yourself to a small number of cells.
>
> Small pen-and-paper puzzles, crosswords, wordsearches, Boggle grids, and grid-deduction puzzles are (of course) welcome, as are connecting walls - but by no means are these the only ways to use small grids and make an interesting puzzle... You may need to think outside (or is that *inside*?!) the box!

Comment: @Stiv How strict is the "square" grid constraint? If the intended restriction is "a small number of cells", how kosher would having _multiple_ small grids be? I have an idea for a puzzle (that I'll likely post regardless) but am wondering how well it fits in this MTC 

Comment: @samm82 I think with this one I was really going for a single grid, to play on the famous phrase involving a single box... But I guess the cells don't have to be *exactly* square - but they ought to be pretty close to it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**List of all questions published as part of the Monthly Topic Challenge #14:**

| Puzzle | Creator |
| --- | --- |
| [The Moldy Square Grid](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/122245/the-moldy-square-grid) | [Amoz](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/70710/amoz) |
| [Sums in a (very small) box](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/122275/sums-in-a-very-small-box) | [Florian F](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/2136/florian-f) |
| [A [Song from Taylor Swift's second album] Puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/122296/a-song-from-taylor-swifts-second-album-puzzle) | [juicifer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/77182/juicifer) |
| [Order the cities, then find which one is not described](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/122342/order-the-cities-then-find-which-one-is-not-described) | [Rand al'Thor](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5373/rand-althor) |
| [Transform a (very small) crossword](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/122349/transform-a-very-small-crossword) | [Jafe](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/41973/jafe) |
| [Intermingled primes](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/122354/intermingled-primes) | [Retudin](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/71170/retudin) |
| [A simple 5x5 crossword](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/122395/a-simple-5x5-crossword) | [Tyler Selden](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/80017/tyler-selden) |
| [Very small regional Yajilin](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/122408/very-small-regional-yajilin) | [Jafe](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/41973/jafe) |
| [The world's smallest square maze?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/122445/the-worlds-smallest-square-maze) | [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644/stiv) |
| [Behaviorists hate this trick](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/122454/behaviorists-hate-this-trick) | [Lukas Rotter](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/37714/lukas-rotter) |

---

The **highest-voted** three of these are:

- [The world's smallest square maze?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/122445) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644), with a score of **26** at the end of the month.
- [Behaviorists hate this trick](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/122454) by [Lukas Rotter](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/37714), with a score of **22** at the end of the month.
- [Order the cities, then find which one is not described](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/122342) by [Rand al'Thor](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5373), with a score of **21** at the end of the month.

The **most viewed** three of these are:

- [Behaviorists hate this trick](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/122454) by [Lukas Rotter](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/37714), with **3020** views at the end of the month.
- [The world's smallest square maze?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/122445) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644), with **2920** views at the end of the month.
- [Sums in a (very small) box](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/122275) by [Florian F](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/2136), with **1314** views at the end of the month.