# Monthly Topic Challenge #15: Multi Puzzle — two (or more) puzzles in one

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This is the fifteenth installment of the Monthly Topic Challenges with topics suggested and voted on [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7265). This month's topic is ***"Multi Puzzle — two (or more) puzzles in one"*** (suggested by [GentlePurpleRain](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/4421)) and will span from the **1st of October to the 31st of October**. During this period, we will compile the list of relevant questions and post it as an answer to this question.

**In the meantime, please go and [propose and vote on future challenges!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7265)**

Everyone have fun, and happy puzzling!

<sub>*Link to [other](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20title%3a%22Monthly%20Topic%20Challenge%20%23) Monthly Topic Challenges.*</sub>

***NOTE***
The suggestion is copied to this post for posterity.

> ### Multi Puzzle — two (or more) puzzles in one
>
> Create a single puzzle that has more than one valid solution, each arrived at in a completely different way.
>
> e.g. Not a riddle that could have two potential solutions, but perhaps a riddle with a single solution, and another message hidden steganographically within the riddle.
>
> Bonus points if the various answers to the puzzle combine somehow to either form a meta-answer or a final meta-puzzle.
>
> This suggestion was inspired by the four **Group 4** puzzles from the [2010 CISRA puzzle competition](https://www.mezzacotta.net/puzzle/cisra/2010/puzzles.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**List of all questions published as part of the Monthly Topic Challenge #15:**

| Puzzle | Creator |
| --- | --- |
| [A sudokey and 14 messages](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/122619/a-sudokey-and-14-messages) | [Retudin](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/71170/retudin) |
| [Additions to menagerie were strange but appreciated](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/122591/additions-to-menagerie-were-strange-but-appreciated) | [Will Octagon Gibson](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/80061/will-octagon-gibson) |