# Fortnightly Topic Challenge #4: Halloween!

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

*Link to [other](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3Aquestion%20Fortnightly%20Topic%20Challenge%20%23) Fortnightly Topics.*

---

This is the fourth installment of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge described [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2841/should-we-have-weekly-fortnightly-topic-challenges) with topics suggested and voted for [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/what-should-be-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges). This fortnight's topic is Halloween **(using the tag [seasonal](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seasonal))**, and will span from Oct. 28 - Nov. 11. During this period, we will compile the list of questions featuring this topic and post it as an answer to this question.

In the meantime, please go [propose and vote on future challenges!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/what-should-be-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges)

Everyone have fun, and happy puzzling!!

Comment: I'm actually surprised by how successful this has been so far :)     I'll try and post my own before the end !!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Questions so far are:

- [Monstrous Morphemes](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23586/monstrous-morphemes) by [Mythi](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/15921/mythi)
- [Pumpkin Carving](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23629/pumpkin-carving) by [Gordon K](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/14135/gordon-k)
- [The Witch Invites](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23637) by [The Dark Truth](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/16608)
- [Spooky Five Words (-----|||||)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23654/spooky-five-words) by [Aggie Kidd](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/9951/aggie-kidd)
- [Contrasting Partners](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23660/contrasting-partners) by [Mythi](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/15921/mythi)
- [There's a Ghost of a Chance!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23690) by [raisinghellyer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/11452)
- [The Witches Have Overdone It](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23715) by [Gordon K](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/14135)
- [Don't get caught by the Hang Man](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23681/dont-get-caught-by-the-hang-man) by [Aggie Kidd](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/9951/aggie-kidd)
- [A Halloween Riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23749) by [GentlePurpleRain](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/4421)