# Fortnightly Topic Challenge #5: Literature

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

*Link to [other](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3Aquestion%20Fortnightly%20Topic%20Challenge%20%23) Fortnightly Topics.*

---

This is the fifth installment of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge described [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2841/should-we-have-weekly-fortnightly-topic-challenges) with topics suggested and voted for [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/what-should-be-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges). This fortnight's topic is [literature](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/literature) (suggested by [alexmc](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/12206/alexmc)), and will span from Nov. 22 - Dec. 5. During this period, we will compile the list of questions featuring this topic and post it as an answer to this question.

In the meantime, please go [propose and vote on future challenges!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/what-should-be-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges)

Everyone have fun, and happy puzzling!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Questions so far are:

- [Emojiture Challenge](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/24124/emojiture-challenge) by [Sleafar](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/15632/sleafar)
- [Emojiture Challenge - Next Generation](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/24157/emojiture-challenge-next-generation) by [Sleafar](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/15632/sleafar)
- [A cipher and a book…?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/24161/a-cipher-and-a-book) by [AJL](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/11790/ajl)
- [Disemvowelled Books](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/24168/disemvowelled-books) by [Gordon K](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/14135/gordon-k)
- [Name me, Who am I?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/24176/name-me-who-am-i) by [Aggie Kidd](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/9951/aggie-kidd)