# Fortnightly Topic Challenge #6: Music

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

*Link to [other](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3Aquestion%20Fortnightly%20Topic%20Challenge%20%23) Fortnightly Topics.*

---

This is the sixth installment of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge described [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2841/should-we-have-weekly-fortnightly-topic-challenges) with topics suggested and voted for [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/what-should-be-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges). This fortnight's topic is [music](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music) (suggested by [CodeNewbie](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/12700/codenewbie)), and will span from Mar. 23 - Apr. 5. During this period, we will compile the list of questions featuring this topic and post it as an answer to this question.

In the meantime, please go [propose and vote on future challenges!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/what-should-be-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges)

Everyone have fun, and happy puzzling!!

Comment: @BmyGuest There is already a list of all challenges [here](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/what-should-be-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges). I don't think adding more links in the question makes it more readable.

Comment: I wouldn't mind using that link instead, but what I was missing was a convenient way to navigate in between the questions, i.e. From the latest to the older ones. I was missing that, and newcomers likely will as well. So they will need to search... (Like I did.)

Comment: I think, I just don't think *here* is a good navigation link. Otherwise, I agree.

Comment: In case I'm not the only one with this issue:  I don't really understand what to do on the propose and vote.  Almost all of the answers are from 4-6 months ago.  Are those still live for voting or are we looking for a new set of answers to vote on?  Most of the options have 5 votes with one having 11, but I'm unsure how many of those votes are from people currently participating or from people who no longer visit the site.  

If it doesn't matter - let me know - but I've been wondering this since the post appeared on Featured.

Comment: @Khale_Kitha We had a couple of challenges last year but at some point they weren't continued. This is the reason why the answers are a couple of months old. However, I don't see a problem with continuing the procedure as before, meaning the answer with most votes will be the next topic.

Comment: Fair enough - I was just curious :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Questions so far are:

- [Musical in Nature](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/28616/musical-in-nature) by [Z. Dailey](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/19731/z-dailey) (asked before start of the challenge, <s>but still not answered</s>)
- [The Recursive Song](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/29458/the-recursive-song) by [Sleafar](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/15632/sleafar)
- [Homage To Robert Johnson](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/29459/homage-to-robert-johnson) by [Hugh Meyers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/18924/hugh-meyers)
- [Musical People Chain](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/29465/musical-people-chain) by [Gordon K](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/14135/gordon-k)
- [What's Jonas trying to hint to me?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/29565/whats-jonas-trying-to-hint-to-me) by [ASCIIThenANSI](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/18770/asciithenansi)
- [The Musing Of the Eggs](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/29571/the-musing-of-the-eggs) by [Khale_Kitha](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/19944/khale-kitha)
- [Don't Misunderstand Me](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/29585/dont-misunderstand-me) by [Sleafar](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/15632/sleafar)
- [Happy Music Challenge, Everyone!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/29610/happy-music-challenge-everyone) by [Hugh Meyers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/18924/hugh-meyers)
- [A Strategy for Sustenance](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/29627/a-strategy-for-sustenance) by [Khale_Kitha](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/19944/khale-kitha)
- [Classic Cryptic Cluing](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/29687/classic-cryptic-cluing) by [Hugh Meyers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/18924/hugh-meyers)
- [Music themed Cryptic Clues](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/29796/music-themed-cryptic-clues) by [Richard Roe](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/17712/richard-roe)
- [A rocking rebus. Find the song!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/29824/a-rocking-rebus-find-the-song) by [Quiquȅ](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/17744/quiqu%C8%85)
- [What song are these lyrics from?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/29950/what-song-are-these-lyrics-from) by [feelinferrety](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/7586/feelinferrety)
- [Historical music](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/29954/historical-music) by [Khale_Kitha](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/19944/khale-kitha)
- [Headbanging Emojis](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/30337/headbanging-emojis) by [Sleafar](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/15632/sleafar)
- [Musician Jumble](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/30346/musician-jumble) by [Will](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/17147/will)

Comment: A really good question ^_^