# Fortnightly Topic Challenge #7: Chess

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

*Link to [other](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3Aquestion%20Fortnightly%20Topic%20Challenge%20%23) Fortnightly Topics.*

---

This is the seventh installment of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge described [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2841/should-we-have-weekly-fortnightly-topic-challenges) with topics suggested and voted for [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/what-should-be-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges). This fortnight's topic is [chess](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chess) (suggested by [rand al'thor](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/5373/rand-althor)), and will span from Apr. 9 - Apr. 22. During this period, we will compile the list of questions featuring this topic and post it as an answer to this question.

In the meantime, please go [propose and vote on future challenges!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/what-should-be-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges)

Everyone have fun, and happy puzzling!!

Comment: [When to use the chess tag?](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/127/when-to-use-the-chess-tag)

Comment: [Which puzzles with chess board must be on-topic here?](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1365/which-puzzles-with-chess-board-must-be-on-topic-here)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Questions so far are:

- [Copycat Chess (Part 1/3)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/30693/copycat-chess-part-1-3) by [Sleafar](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/15632/sleafar)
- [Copycat Chess (Part 2/3)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/30697/copycat-chess-part-2-3) by [Sleafar](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/15632/sleafar)
- [Copycat Chess (Part 3/3)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/30707/copycat-chess-part-3-3) by [Sleafar](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/15632/sleafar)
- [A Chess Puzzle With a Twist](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/30757/a-chess-puzzle-with-a-twist) by [Sleafar](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/15632/sleafar)
- [Are you more clever than Alice?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/30760/are-you-more-clever-than-alice) by [klm123](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/28/klm123)
- [Replace a piece to checkmate](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/30797/replace-a-piece-to-checkmate) by [Julian Rosen](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/2627/julian-rosen)
- [Questions about grandpa (with chess puzzle clue)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/30868/questions-about-grandpa-with-chess-puzzle-clue) by [Julian Rosen](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/2627/julian-rosen)
- [Chess Themed cryptic clues](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/31012/chess-themed-cryptic-clues) by [Richard Roe](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/17712/richard-roe)
- [Eight queens on the chessboard with mirrors](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/31107/eight-queens-on-the-chessboard-with-mirrors) by [Haobin](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/9404/haobin)
- [An Easy Mate In 1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/31112/an-easy-mate-in-1) by [Sleafar](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/15632/sleafar)
- [Chess with bouncing and explosion](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/31154/chess-with-bouncing-and-explosion) by [wythagoras](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/16322/wythagoras)
- [A Puzzle That Marches Swiftly To The Median](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/31179/a-puzzle-that-marches-swiftly-to-the-median) by [Hugh Meyers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/18924/hugh-meyers)
- [Chess Fortnight is finally over!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/31377/chess-fortnight-is-finally-over) by [Deusovi](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/11876/deusovi)