# Fortnightly Topic Challenge #8: Visual

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

*Link to [other](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3Aquestion%20Fortnightly%20Topic%20Challenge%20%23) Fortnightly Topics.*

---

This is the eighth installment of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge described [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2841/should-we-have-weekly-fortnightly-topic-challenges), with topics suggested and voted for [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/what-should-be-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges). This fortnight's topic is [visual](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visual) (suggested by [GentlePurpleRain](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/4421/gentlepurplerain)), and will span from April 25 – May 6. During this period, we will compile the list of questions featuring this topic and post it as an answer to this question.

In the meantime, please go [propose and vote on future challenges!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/what-should-be-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges)

Everyone have fun, and happy puzzling!!

Comment: While I love(d) [tag:visual], I do not seem to find it unter the "propose and vote" link above. ? Where do we suggest/propose if not there?

Comment: @BmyGuest - That's the right link. After a suggestion becomes the official fortnightly topic, it gets deleted from that thread (aside: now that we've graduated, you need 10k rep to see the deleted posts).

Comment: @Alconja, ah, makes sense now :c)

Answer (score 9):

Questions so far are:

- [Bar-coded Message (Reverse Engineering)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/31408/sigint-challenge-3-reverse-engineering) by [2012rcampion](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/9718/2012rcampion)
- [An array of possibilities on board](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/31370/an-array-of-possibilities-on-board) by [keyboardwielder](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/20538/keyboardwielder)
- [You have prepared. You are determined. You approach the door](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/31557) by [Alconja](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5208/alconja)

  [LEVEL connections](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/31627/level-connections) by [Beastly Gerbil](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/18250/beastly-gerbil?tab=profile)

  [A sum of images](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/31564/a-sum-of-images) by [Wu33o](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/20690/wu33o)

  [Help me, help my best friend please](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/31583/help-me-help-my-best-friend-please) by [patient-zero](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/21591/patient-zero)

  [Going to the movies](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/31691/going-to-the-movies) by [Wu33o](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/20690/wu33o)

  [A peculiar painting](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/31832/a-peculiar-painting) by [knrumsey](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/11063/knrumsey)

  [The mystery flag](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/31911/the-mystery-flag) by [Beastly Gerbil](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/18250/beastly-gerbil?tab=profile)

  [What does this picture rebus represent?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/31951/what-does-this-picture-rebus-represent) by [Quiquȅ](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/17744/quiqu%C8%85)

  [Little bits of food](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/32046/little-bits-of-food) by [scholtes](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/21836/scholtes)

  [A case of academic misconduct?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/32082/a-case-of-academic-misconduct) by [cpj](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/7545/cpj)

  [Prevent a Terror Attack](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/32135/prevent-a-terror-attack) by [Sleafar](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/15632/sleafar)

Comment: Added a visual posted just before the start of the period, if that's not OK just remove it :)

Comment: @JonathanAllan: Thanks. Actually, I made that puzzle for the _previous_ fortnightly challenge.  I couldn't use that tag on the puzzle without revealing the answer, and updating the corresponding meta post would be a spoiler as well.  After submitting it, I hopped over to see what the next theme was going to be and was pleasantly surprised.

Comment: @KeyboardWielder - yes I realise that now :) Wonderful puzzle IMO - I was looking for symmetry / coordinate-change relationships

Comment: Added my most recent one

Comment: Added some more so its up to date