# Fortnightly Topic Challenge #9: Language

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

*Link to [other](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3Aquestion%20Fortnightly%20Topic%20Challenge%20%23) Fortnightly Topics.*

---

This is the ninth installment of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge described [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2841/should-we-have-weekly-fortnightly-topic-challenges), with topics suggested and voted for [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/what-should-be-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges). This fortnight's topic is [language](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language) (suggested by [question_asker](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/17250/question-asker), and will span from May 13 – May 26. During this period, we will compile the list of questions featuring this topic and post it as an answer to this question.

In the meantime, please go [propose and vote on future challenges!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/what-should-be-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges)

Everyone have fun, and happy puzzling!!

Answer (score 5):

Questions so far are:

- [Future or past, depending on the country](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/32606/future-or-past-depending-on-the-country) by [wythagoras](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/16322/wythagoras)
- [A Strange Correspondence](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/32640/16717) by [Jonathan Allan](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/16717/jonathan-allan)
- [A Letter: When Sherlock meets Moriarty](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/32669/a-letter-when-sherlock-meets-moriarty) by [manshu](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/17482/manshu)
- [The Language Genie](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/32916/the-language-genie) by [hexomino](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/18422/hexomino)
- [A mysterious telephone message](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/32956/a-mysterious-telephone-message) by [GentlePurpleRain](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/4421/gentlepurplerain)
- [A Greek cipher about 2 lovers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/33018/a-greek-cipher-about-2-lovers?s=2|0.0000) by [Decypher](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/1934/decypher)
- [Elle Rend Le Coeur Plus Amoureux](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/33057/elle-rend-le-coeur-plus-amoreux?s=1|0.0000) by [Hugh Meyers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/18924/hugh-meyers)
- [Breaking up is fun to do](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/33501/breaking-up-is-fun-to-do) by [Dan Russell](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/21234/dan-russell)