# Fortnightly Topic Challenge #10: Science

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

*Link to [other](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3Aquestion%20Fortnightly%20Topic%20Challenge%20%23) Fortnightly Topics.*

---

This is the tenth installment of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge described [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2841/should-we-have-weekly-fortnightly-topic-challenges), with topics suggested and voted for [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/what-should-be-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges). This fortnight's topic is [science](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science) (suggested by [NeedAName](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/13970/needaname)), and will span from June 1st – June 14th. During this period, we will compile the list of questions featuring this topic and post it as an answer to this question.

In the meantime, please go [propose and vote on future challenges!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/what-should-be-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges)

Everyone have fun, and happy puzzling!!

Comment: I find your lack of "She blinded me with science" reference in this post ... disturbing...

Answer (score 2):

Questions so far are :

- [A troubling doubling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/33839/a-troubling-doubling) by [Dan Russell](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/21234/dan-russell)
- [Where the water is hotter](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/34920/20274) by [kamenf](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/15856/kamenf)
- [My two favorite scientists](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/34943/my-two-favorite-scientists) by [Lord of dark](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/20274/lord-of-dark)
- [Game of science!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/34981/game-of-science) by [Brent Hackers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/22895/brent-hackers)
- [An easy science/nerd riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/35161/an-easy-science-nerd-riddle) by [Brent Hackers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/22895/brent-hackers)
- [Infinite precision](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/35166/infinite-precision) by [dan1111](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/21939/dan1111)
- [Mad Scientist Murdered!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/35248/mad-scientist-murdered) by [NeedAName](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/13970/needaname)
- [Science: Spaced Out and Obfuscated](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/35309/science-spaced-out-and-obfuscated) by [Hugh Meyers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/18924/hugh-meyers)
- [A girl and a guy](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/35568/a-girl-and-a-guy) by [Dan Russell](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/21234/dan-russell)
- [A Mythical Member of the Scientific Community](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/35664/a-mythical-member-of-the-scientific-community) by [hexomino](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/18422/hexomino)
- [Who are we? The pure ones](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/35747/who-are-we-the-pure-ones) by [Roland](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/13237/roland)