# Fortnightly Topic Challenge #11: Steganography

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

*Link to [other](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3Aquestion%20Fortnightly%20Topic%20Challenge%20%23) Fortnightly Topics.*

---

This is the eleventh installment of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge described [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2841/should-we-have-weekly-fortnightly-topic-challenges), with topics suggested and voted for [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/what-should-be-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges). This fortnight's topic is [steganography](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/steganography) (suggested by [Alconja](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5208/alconja)), and will span from June 24th – July 8th. During this period, we will compile the list of questions featuring this topic and post it as an answer to this question.

**In the meantime, please go [propose and vote on future challenges!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/what-should-be-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges)**

Everyone have fun, and happy puzzling!!

Comment: Here's the tag wiki for [tag:steganography]: `Hidden messages concealed in otherwise unsuspicious pictures, text, and/or audio.`

Comment: @Emrakul When exactly do we start new Fortnightly challenges? Is it time for the 12th by now?

Comment: @BmyGuest I'm not sure! There's no set time, I think. We've just been going with "whenever someone wants to start the top-voted challenge," to this point, I think.

Answer (score 2):

Questions so far are:

- [Gain Access to the Café's Internet](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/36671/gain-access-to-the-caf%c3%a9s-internet) by [Will](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/17147/will)
- [How was the math test?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/36806/how-was-the-math-test) by [Dan Russell](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/21234/dan-russell)
- [A Puzzle That Doubles Back Obscurely](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/36861/a-puzzle-that-doubles-back-obscurely) by [Hugh Meyers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/18924/hugh-meyers)
- [Some of our Professors are Missing](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/36969/some-of-our-professors-are-missing) by [Gordon K](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/14135/gordon-k)
- [Steganography TriBond™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/37004/steganography-tribond) by [humn](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/18129/humn)
- [♦ Series - Getting a free donut](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/36922/getting-a-free-donut) by [Peanut](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/9993/peanut)

Comment: Don't forget: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/36922/getting-a-free-donut

Comment: @MorganG, I've added that puzzle to the community wiki.

Comment: Oh, sorry! didn't realize I could have edited that myself