# Fortnightly Topic Challenge #12: Mazes

Tags: discussion, questions, topic-challenge

*Link to [other](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3Aquestion%20Fortnightly%20Topic%20Challenge%20%23) Fortnightly Topics.*

---

This is the twelth installment of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge described [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2841/should-we-have-weekly-fortnightly-topic-challenges), with topics suggested and voted for [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/what-should-be-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges). This fortnight's topic is [mazes](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mazes) (suggested by [BmyGuest](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5840/bmyguest)), and will span from July 13th – July 26th. During this period, we will compile the list of questions featuring this topic and post it as an answer to this question.

**In the meantime, please go [propose and vote on future challenges!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/what-should-be-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges)**

Everyone have fun, and happy puzzling!!

Comment: I'm entering this Fortnightly Topic Challenge like I did with [the last one](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5037/fortnightly-topic-challenge-11-steganography).

Comment: Here's the tag wiki for [tag:mazes]: `A tour puzzle in the form of a complex branching passage through which the solver must find a route.`

Comment: Great choice of fortnightly topic @BmyGuest!

Comment: @JonathanAllan - Literally just came here to make the same comment/compliment. An excellent turn out of quality stuff this fortnight. So thanks from me too, both for the suggestion, and for your content contributions.

Answer (score 6):

Questions so far are:

- [Alice and the Fractal Hedge Maze](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/37675/alice-and-the-fractal-hedge-maze) by [Mike Earnest](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/10615/mike-earnest)
- [A-maze-ing Wordsearch](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/37645/a-maze-ing-wordsearch) by [BmyGuest](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5840/bmyguest)
- [A-maze-ing Dice](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/37725/a-maze-ing-dice) by [BmyGuest](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5840/bmyguest)
- [The Persistence Of Memory](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/37750/the-persistence-of-memory) by [Deusovi](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/11876/deusovi)
- [A-maze-ing Tiles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/37785/a-maze-ing-tiles) by [BmyGuest](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5840/bmyguest)
- [A Maze of Characters](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/37889/list-of-characters) by [Peanut](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/9993/peanut)
- [A Mqze of Miszpeked Worfs](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/37929/a-mqze-of-miszpeked-worfs)  by [Peanut](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/9993/peanut)
- [A Maze of Colors](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/37946/a-maze-of-colors) by [Peanut](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/9993/peanut)
- [Cryptic Clue Maze](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/38037/cryptic-clue-maze) by [Dan Russell](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/21234/dan-russell)
- [A-maze-ing Navigation](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/38041/a-maze-ing-navigation) by [BmyGuest](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5840/bmyguest)
- [The maze of letters - Clue Three](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/38072/the-maze-of-letters-clue-three) by [Mithrandir](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/25966/mithrandir)
- [Number-maze (1,...,560)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/38052/number-maze-1-560) by [Rosie F](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/22922/rosie-f)
- [They've Noticed Your Puzzling Prowess](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/38214/theyve-noticed-your-puzzling-prowess) by [Jonathan Allan](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/16717/jonathan-allan)
- [The Knight and the Maze](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/38324/the-knight-and-the-maze) by [hexomino](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/18422/hexomino)
- [The Collapse of Memory](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/38405/the-collapse-of-memory) by [Deusovi](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/11876/deusovi)
- [Labyrinthus Londoninensis, or The Equestrian Perplexed](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/37935) by [GentlePurpleRain](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/4421/gentlepurplerain)

Comment: Currently, 3 of the [tag:mazes] in that list start with `A-maze-ing`.

Comment: ...because the form a series of the same author :-)

Comment: Oh. I didn't notice that.