# Fortnightly Topic Challenge #13: Sports, for the Rio Olympics!

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This is the thirteenth installment of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge described [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2841/should-we-have-weekly-fortnightly-topic-challenges), with topics suggested and voted for [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/what-should-be-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges). This fortnight's topic is, **in the theme of the Rio Olympics**, [sports](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sports) (suggested by [Gordon K](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/14135/gordon-k)), and will span from August 5th – August 18th. During this period, we will compile the list of questions featuring this topic and post it as an answer to this question.

**In the meantime, please go [propose and vote on future challenges!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/what-should-be-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges)**

Everyone have fun, and happy puzzling!

---

*Link to [other](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3Aquestion%20Fortnightly%20Topic%20Challenge%20%23) Fortnightly Topics.*

Comment: So the theme is really puzzles tagged sports, not  using any subject matter regarding "the Olympics"? So I should not add [Chess at the 2020 Olympic Games](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/40174/16717)?

Comment: @JonathanAllan Good point; I've clarified the title.

Comment: I already have a Rio Olympics puzzle, but I'm not posting it until someone gets the answer to [Going back to the Stack](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/39000/going-back-to-the-stack).

Comment: Eh. It's only for fun. I don't think it matters if the link is tenuous.

Answer (score 9):

**List of [all questions published](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=[sports]%20created%3a2016-08-05..2016-08-18%20is%3aquestion) as part of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge #13:**

- [An Olympic Connecting Wall](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/40306/an-olympic-connecting-wall) by [DooplissForce](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/23521/dooplissforce)
- [Athletes at the Rio Olympics](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/40481/athletes-at-the-rio-olympics) by [IAmInPLS](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/25957/iaminpls)
- [Desperate Housewives in Brazil](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/40293/desperate-housewives-in-brazil) by [Artur Kirkoryan](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/14140/artur-kirkoryan)
- [Free Tickets to Rio!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/40310/free-tickets-to-rio) by [Ankoganit](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/25412/ankoganit)
- [Rebuilding the Rio 2016 Olympics logo](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/40529/rebuilding-the-rio-2016-olympics-logo) by [BmyGuest](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5840/bmyguest)
- [These pictures are out of order, but how should they be?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/40344/2071) by [David Starkey](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/2071/david-starkey)

---

The **highest-voted** of these is [Free Tickets to Rio!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/40310/free-tickets-to-rio) by [Ankoganit](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/25412/ankoganit), with a score of **39** at the end of the fortnight.

The **most viewed** is probably [Desperate Housewives in Brazil](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/40293/desperate-housewives-in-brazil) by [Artur Kirkoryan](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/14140/artur-kirkoryan), with 4000 views as of 5 September (not sure how many during the fortnight itself).