# Fortnightly Topic Challenge #14: History

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This is the fourteenth installment of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge described [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2841/should-we-have-weekly-fortnightly-topic-challenges), with topics suggested and voted for [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/what-should-be-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges). This fortnight's topic is [history](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) (suggested by [manshu](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/17482/manshu)), and will span from August 22nd – September 4th. During this period, we will compile the list of questions featuring this topic and post it as an answer to this question.

**In the meantime, please go [propose and vote on future challenges!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/what-should-be-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges)**

Everyone have fun, and happy puzzling!

---

*Link to [other](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=views%3a0%20title%3a"Fortnightly%20Topic%20Challenge%20%23") Fortnightly Topics.*

Comment: That link to the other fortnightly topics should use this search term: `views:0 title:"Fortnightly Topic Challenge #"`. `views:0` is the same as `is:question`, `title:"Fortnightly Topic Challenge #"` ensures the text is in the title, not somewhere else. The link should be this: [/search?tab=newest&q=views%3a0%20title%3a%22Fortnightly%20Topic%20Challenge%20%23%22](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=views%3a0%20title%3a%22Fortnightly%20Topic%20Challenge%20%23%22)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*[Is no-one interested in history?](https://youtu.be/zNR6EfZ6oas?t=36)*

---

**List of [all questions published](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=[history]%20created%3a2016-08-22..2016-09-04%20is%3aquestion) as part of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge #14:**

- [5 Quotes 1 Figure](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/41448/5-quotes-1-figure) by [dcfyj](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/22684/dcfyj)
- [A mysterious email from the Historical Society](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/41963/a-mysterious-email-from-the-historical-society) by [rand al'thor](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5373/rand-althor)
- [And the rest is hstr!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/41375/and-the-rest-is-hstr) by [IAmInPLS](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/25957/iaminpls)
- [Five Historical Features](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/41277/five-historical-features) by [Hugh Meyers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/18924/hugh-meyers)
- [Historical Crossword Puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/41226/historical-crossword-puzzle) by [Sleafar](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/15632/sleafar)
- [Historical figure sudoku](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/41383/historical-figure-sudoku) by [Maria Deleva](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/29050/maria-deleva)
- [Historical figure word-search](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/41417/historical-figure-word-search) by [Maria Deleva](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/29050/maria-deleva)
- [Historical figures word search with a twist](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/41793/historical-figures-word-search-with-a-twist) by [Maria Deleva](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/29050/maria-deleva)
- [Historical Quotes](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/41299/historical-quotes) by [Sleafar](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/15632/sleafar)
- [Only Kinect Wall](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/41522/only-kinect-wall) by [David Starkey](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/2071/david-starkey)
- [The past is never dead. It's not even past.](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/41489/the-past-is-never-dead-its-not-even-past) by [Ankoganit](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/25412/ankoganit)
- [The Writings of Impostradamus](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/41903/the-writings-of-impostradamus) by [hexomino](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/18422/hexomino)
- [What is this historic place?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/41968/what-is-this-historic-place) by [celtschk](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/14010/celtschk)
- [Where do all the doors lead to?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/41490/where-do-all-the-doors-lead-to) by [Maria Deleva](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/29050/maria-deleva)
- [Who was the powerful woman?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/41397/who-was-the-powerful-woman) by [celtschk](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/14010/celtschk)

---

The **highest-voted** of these is [And the rest is hstr!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/41375/and-the-rest-is-hstr) by [IAmInPLS](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/25957/iaminpls), with a score of **33** at the end of the fortnight.

The **most viewed** is [Where do all the doors lead to?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/41490/where-do-all-the-doors-lead-to) by [Maria Deleva](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/29050/maria-deleva), with approximately **4000** views during the fortnight.