# Fortnightly Topic Challenge #15: Stories

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This is the fifteenth installment of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge described [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2841/should-we-have-weekly-fortnightly-topic-challenges), with topics suggested and voted on [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/what-should-be-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges). This fortnight's topic is [story](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story) (suggested by [GentlePurpleRain](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/4421/gentlepurplerain)), and will span from the **5th of September to the 18th of September**. During this period, we will compile the list of questions with this tag and post it as an answer to this question.

**In the meantime, please go and [propose and vote on future challenges!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/what-should-be-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges)**

Everyone have fun, and happy puzzling!

---

*Link to [other](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20title%3a"Fortnightly%20Topic%20Challenge%20%23") Fortnightly Topics.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**List of [all questions published](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=[story]%20created%3a2016-09-05..2016-09-18%20is%3aquestion) as part of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge #15:**

- [The princess arrived safely at the castle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42096) by [M D](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/29050)
- [The Sorns are Demanding Ransom: Can You Help?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42145) by [RedstoneGeek](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/22637)
- [Vizzini has captured Buttercup!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/42186/5373) by [Sconibulus](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5297)
- [Megan & the numeric cipher (693264475 etc)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42198/megan-the-numeric-cipher-693264475-etc) by [Rosie F](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/22922/rosie-f)
- [Labryca — Floor 4: I've Just Seen a Face](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42213/labryca-floor-4-ive-just-seen-a-face) by [A. Mirabeau](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/25719/a-mirabeau)
- [Weird messages from a friend](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42318/weird-messages-from-a-friend) by [Lukas Rotter](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/14478/lukas-rotter)
- [A murder in the Puzznk rock band](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42333/a-murder-in-the-puzznk-rock-band) by [rand al'thor](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5373)
- [Identify the correct cabin using Paper and SELFie stick](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42418/identify-the-correct-cabin-using-paper-and-selfie-stick) by [Sathi Reddy](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/29090/sathi-reddy)
- [Cipher Ciphe Ciph](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42553/cipher-ciphe-ciph) by [TheBitByte](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/29958/thebitbyte)
- [How did he know which rose to pick?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42585/how-did-he-know-which-rose-to-pick) by [rsp](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/29679/rsp)
- [The shrink and his patient (Part 1)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42631/the-shrink-and-his-patient-part-1) by [IAmInPLS](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/25957/iaminpls)
- [Mithrandir has lost his keys!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42656/mithrandir-has-lost-his-keys) by [rand al'thor](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5373)
- [What is the meaning of Samuel's life?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42696/what-is-the-meaning-of-samuels-life) by [celtschk](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/14010/celtschk)
- [A strange crazy lady and her ramblings](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42733/a-strange-crazy-lady-and-her-ramblings) by [M D](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/29050)

---

The **highest-voted** of these is [Mithrandir has lost his keys!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/42656/5373) by [rand al'thor](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5373), with a score of **42** at the end of the fortnight.

The **most viewed** is either [Mithrandir has lost his keys!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/42656/5373) (again) or [Vizzini has captured Buttercup!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/42186/5373) by [Sconibulus](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5297), each with approximately **2000** views during the fortnight.